# Как выводить на экран и вводить данные типа wchar_t[]?

Tags: c, windows, unicode, mingw

Вопрос в том, как это сделать на Windows. На Linux-е это просто

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
//а потом wprintf ...
```

На Windows такое не катит.
Желательно, чтобы вышло как-то так.

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
#elif defined _WIN32
  //Windows
#else
```

Нужно для вывода кириллицы, иероглифов и т. п.
Нужен именно **wchar_t**.

P. S. **MinGW** gcc -dumpversion **4.8.1**

P. P. S. На MS Visual C++ 2010 работает ответ 1 (без stdafx.h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О мой бог, cygwin мне помог... -- говорил когда-то святой Георгий.

Cygwin выручил и меня!

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
#elif defined _WIN32
  //Windows
#else
```

Теперь и этого не надо!

Просто

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
```

Работает и на Linux, и на Windows (cygwin1.dll).

Версия компилятора g++: **4.9.2**.

Версия Windows: **XP SP3**.

Comment: Ох, Windows XP! Понятно тогда, в старых версиях многое работает не так, как надо.

Comment: На Windows 7 предложенные решения не работали!

Comment: @VladD: На Windows 7 предложенные решения не работали!

Comment: Даже так? Ну что ж, тем лучше, что нашлось универсальное решение.

Comment: Если ваше решение помогло — не бойтесь отмечать его галочкой.

Comment: @VladD: Это можно сделать только завтра

Comment: @VladD: MinGW w64!

Comment: А `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` не поможет вместо `system("chcp 65001 >log.txt");`?

Comment: Нет. Кстати, понял что system("chcp 65001 >log.txt"); utf-8, а мне надо 16.

Comment: VladD: Или очень стрёмный UTF-16.

Comment: VladD: В смысле большинство символов занимает 2 wchar_t.

Comment: @VladD: У MinGW w64 есть большие странности. Не буду перечислять их. Из-за этих странностей промежуточное решение - cygwin.

Comment: Только будут проблемы с переносом программки на другой комп (где cygwin не поставлен). И кстати, не помню уж точно где, но я с ним нарывался, некотрые функции работают как-то не так (не как в \*nix-ах). Из эмуляторов \*nix в винде мне больше всего понравился [Interix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix) (к сожалению, закончился на XP SP2)

Comment: @avp: У меня вроде бы работало, если утащить с каталогом программы все нужные dll-ки.

Comment: @VladD, возможно они что-то улучшили (я к cygwin давно не прикасался)

Answer (score 3):

Традиционно поддержка Unicode в консоли Windows очень слаба, и вероятно для Windows вам стоит задуматься о графическом интерфейсе (в нём как раз обычно всё в порядке). В «свежих» версиях Visual Studio рантайм стал умнее, и с поддержкой Unicode стало лучше.

Тем не менее, вам нужен как минимум шрифт, поддерживающий Unicode (например, Lucida Console).

Например, мой экземпляр Visual Studio 2013 с вот таким исходником:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"%s", L"кошка \x65e5\x672c\x56fd\n");
    return 0;
}
```

выдал на экран кириллицу, но не иероглифы. При редиректе вывода в файл, однако, всё читается правильно. (Это означает, что проблема в шрифте.) С выводом RTL-текстов (иврит, арабский), однако, всё ещё возможны проблемы.

Информация взята [отсюда](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx).

(Ответ относится к toolchain'у Visual Studio.)

Comment: Спасибо, но я использую и буду использовать minGW, где stdafx.h нет. _setmode, _O_U16TEXT компилятор не нашёл.

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: А там не подходит тот же рецепт, что и в Unix, с юникодным шрифтом в консоли?

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: Вот [эта ссылка](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/) утверждает, что вовсе ничего не нужно делать особенного. (Но вы всё же выставьте нужный шрифт в свойствах консоли.)

Comment: У меня именно MinGW, не w64

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон, setmode() (и _setmode()) там есть (нужен `<windows.h>`), а вот где искать `_O_U16TEXT` не знаю.

Comment: Если в системе переключиться на японскую локаль для не-юникод приложений, то иероглифы из вашего примера станут отображаться, а кириллица - нет.

Comment: _O_U16TEXT = 0x20000 (#define)

Comment: _setmode отыскался. Сейчас попробую

Comment: http://pastebin.com/thKNk3bx (выдержка из fcntl.h)

Comment: Убрал stdafx.h. В итоге не выводит ничего

Comment: А точнее, i/o error/

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: А вы не забыли `-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE` и `-municode` для линковки?

Comment: @VladD: http://picpaste.com/pics/_________________-MJZBypRR.1436272191.png

Comment: @VladD: Через -DUNICODE скомпилилось, тот же резулятат

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: Подождите, а почему `%s`, когда надо `%ls`? (В Visual Studio баг, поэтому для него `%s`.)

Comment: @VladD: не знаю. %ls и %s почему-то работает на VC++ Express одинаково

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: Угу, это да, но там баг. А на MinGW?

Comment: @VladD: Не помогло

Comment: @VladD: а на GCC (на GNU/Linux) имеет значение

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: Да, [имеет](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wprintf.3.html) по идее: _`s`: If no `l` modifier is present: The `const char *` argument is expected [...] If an `l` modifier is present: The `const wchar_t *` argument is expected._

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: А ошибка на MinGW с `%ls` та же?

Comment: @VladD: Вывод такой же - I/O error .

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: Странно. А если попробовать вообще убрать `_setmode`? Или использовать `_setmode` с `_O_U8TEXT = 0x40000`? Должно же оно как-то работать.

Comment: @VladD: http://www.cyberforum.ru/post7847642.html

Comment: @VladD: Попытаюсь изобрести велосипед.

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: Вот [этот ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10765469/276994) предлагает выполнить в консоли `chcp 10000`. Может, это поможет в вашем случае?

Comment: @VladD: Не помогло

Comment: @VladD: Вопрос можно закрыть. Cygwin мне помог, см. мой ответ.

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон: Отлично, разобрались! Может быть, имеет смысл включить версию Windows и компилятора в ваш ответ.

Comment: @VladD: сделано.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно вызвать `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"Testing unicode -- English -- Ελληνικά -- Español." << std::endl;
    // или
    wprintf(L"Testing unicode -- English -- Ελληνικά -- Español.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Поддержка конкретных символов зависит от шрифта консоли. Lucida Console и Consolas справляются со всем, кроме иероглифов.

<sub>Решение взято из ответа на en-SO - [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543/1988244)</sub>

Comment: Не идёт. Можно попозже с Вами, пожалуйста, я разбираюсь с первым ответом. Если можете, помогите.

Comment: @ЖелезоПитон Первый ответ отредактирован и теперь совпадает с этим решением. У вас сам по себе файл исходника как unicode сохранен? Попробуйте студией собрать в конце-концов, вдруг проблема в MinGW.

Comment: @PashapPash: Проблема точно в MinGW. Студия устанавливается