# C++11 string literal u8

Tags: c++, unicode

Решил написать небольшой пример:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << u8"это строка6" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Устанавливаю в консоли кодовую страницу с помощью следующей команды:
chcp 65001

Выполняю программу, и получаю следующий вывод:

```
��то строка6
```

Почему первый символ отобразился неправильно?
Судя по выводу, при использовании литерала u8, BOM в начало не добавляется.
Это кодировка 65001 думает, что в начале идет BOM, пытается прочитать его,
а остальное выводит нормально. Тогда хотелось бы найти кодировку UTF-8 без BOM.

**Дополнения:**
Файл сохранен также в utf8 without BOM. Если перенаправить в файл, то запишется нормально.
Компилятор Mingw с версией gcc 5.0. Система - Windows.

Comment: Какой компилятор? Это важно. Система, я так понимаю, Windows?

Comment: А с `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);` работает? (взято [отсюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434173/10105))

Comment: @VladD в Mingw вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: @VladD, в *gnu/linux* после компиляции `test.cpp` командой `make test CPPFLAGS=-std=c++0x` бинарник при запуске не выдаёт никакик *bom-ов*. первые байты: `d1 8d d1 82 d0 be 20 d1`, вполне валидный *utf8*.

Comment: @andrei.aliashkevich, а если перенаправить вывод программы в файл, запишется тоже с *bom-ом*? / кстати, а в исходник не «затесалось», случайно, какого-нибудь мусора?

Comment: Скорее всего исходник сохранен в обычном cp1251. В этом случае буква э кодируется с помощью FD. А так как консоли Вы сказали "будет UTF-8", то она и попыталась распарсить. А FD - это начало 6байтовых последовательностей. Распарсить не удалось, поэтому и вставило ромбик с знаком вопроса. А вот почему дальше нормально - это нужно отдельно исследовать. Может консоль догадалась:)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin BOM тут не причем. `std::cout << u8" это строка6" << std::endl;` (с пробелом в начале) выводится нормально.

Comment: Ну да, с пробелом нормально выводит. У меня идеи закончились.

Comment: Еще одно интересное замечание: если первым символом будет буква латинского алфавита, а следующие, допустим, русского алфавита, то текст выведется нормально.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в отличии от других систем, консоль в windows, это не просто файл, принимающий поток байт. И где-то внутри std::cout идет преобразование, либо в oem-кодировку, либо в utf-16 (точно не знаю). При этом никто не запрещает выполнять  это преобразование хоть побайтово и использовать в вызовах соответствующих системных API. Поэтому, например, `puts("\302\260")` выводит символ корректно, а  `putc('\302', stdout); putc('\260', stdout);` - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам не использовать utf-8 при выводе в консоль на Windows (режим utf-8 имеет баги), вместо этого пользоваться "широкими" потоками ([подробнее про использование юникода в Windows](http://utf8everywhere.org/#how))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>         // std::wcerr

std::wstring strtows(const std::string &str, UINT codePage)
{
    std::wstring ws;
    int n = MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, str.c_str(), static_cast<int>(str.size()), NULL, 0);
    if (n) {
        ws.resize(n);
        if (MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, str.c_str(), static_cast<int>(str.size()), &ws[0], n) == 0)
            ws.clear();
    }
    return ws;
}

std::string wstostr(const std::wstring &ws, UINT codePage)
{
    // prior to C++11 std::string and std::wstring were not guaranteed to have their memory be contiguous,
    // although all real-world implementations make them contiguous
    std::string str;
    int srcLen = static_cast<int>(ws.size());
    int n = WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, ws.c_str(), srcLen, NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (n) {
        str.resize(n);
        if (WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, ws.c_str(), srcLen, &str[0], n, 0, NULL) == 0)
            str.clear();
    }
    return str;
}

std::string WstringToUtf8(const std::wstring &str)
{
    return wstostr(str, CP_UTF8);
}

std::wstring Utf8ToWstring(const std::string &str)
{

    return strtows(str, CP_UTF8);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << Utf8ToWstring(u8"это строка6") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего придется написать класс (string), представляющий строки в utf8. Может есть какие готовые реализации?

Comment: @andrei.aliashkevich общепринятой практикой является хранение utf-8 внутри std::string. Однако при этом нужно быть аккуратным при выводе строк или передаче их в другое api.

Comment: Хранить в std::string можно, но только хранить. вызов length() уже не вернет количество символов в строке. Получить отдельный символ посредством индекса также не получится. Поэтому и хочу написать класс, который реализует все это.

Comment: @andrei.aliashkevich стандарт C++ не гарантирует, что length возвращает кол-во символов. Он возвращает количество байтов. На самом деле, доступ к отдельным символам требуется редко. Чтобы сделать быстрый доступ по индексу, придется использовать шестибайтные символы, что затратно. Проще написать пару доп. функций, например Utf8StrLen и Utf8SubStr, чем писать еще один  велосипед.

Comment: Нуууу, во времена ASCII и два байта на символ считалось «затратно». Не вижу проблем использовать хоть восьмибайтные символы, если это позволит получить произвольный доступ. (По факту, в utf8 произвольного доступа по индексу нету, это чисто потоковый формат.) Память, слава богу, уже давно не узкое место.

Comment: @VladD в принципе хватит и 4 байт (согласно последнему RFC). Другое дело, что это не решит ни проблему подсчета символов, ни произвольного доступа к произвольному символу, потому что unicode code point != отображаемый символ.

Comment: @zenden2k: Ну, можно ограничить количество акцентов (то есть, по сути дополнительных символов в code point) десятком, и впихнуть всё в 8 байт, например. (В качестве минуса этого подхода, пропадёт «поддержка» ZALGO.)

Comment: @VladD а если еще вспомнить, что юникодная строка может быть BIDI, и есть 3 типа символов с точки зрения изменения направления, то делать что-либо с этой строкой расхочется. Поэтому, если вы не разрабатываете текстовый редактор, лучше не лезть в эти дебри.

Comment: @zenden2k: unicode code point != отображаемый символ. С этого места поподробней пожалуйста.

Comment: @andrei.aliashkevich, из [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point): In character encoding terminology, a **code point** or code position is any of the numerical values that make up the code space. Many code points represent single characters **but** they can also have **other meanings**, such as **for formatting**.