# Русский язык в консоли

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, кириллица, c++-faq

Учу C++ по книжке Страуструпа, не выводятся русские символы.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    string previous = " ";
    string current;

    while (cin >> current)
    {
        if (previous == current)
        {
            cout << "Повторяющееся слово: " << current << endl;
        }

        previous = current;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

"Повторяющееся слово: " - отображается нормально благодаря setlocale.
То что после - крякозяблы, хотя повторяющееся слова находит.
setlocale пробовал разные (0, ""), "", "Rus" и пр.

В Code::Blocks всё работает и без крякозяблов. Даже без setlocale.

Comment: увы, но setlocale Вас не спасёт, единственный вариант нормальный это сменить кодировку в консоли

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь!

Comment: @VladD, достаточно набрать в поисковике: "[C++] русский язык". Правда там куча вариантов, надо поискать с годным ответом. Может этот: [Русские символы при вводе и выводе на C++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/117144)

Comment: @AlexKrass нормальный пример, с минус пятью

Comment: @VladD, нашёл пример с CharToOem, вполне годно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/70089/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2-dev-c

Comment: @VladD а ответа с использованием Unicode, а не 1251, нет?

Comment: @PashaPash: Хороший вопрос! Надо бы наведаться в чат C++-минус-C, затребовать у тамошних гуру канонический (ТМ) ответ.

Comment: @VladD о, нашел - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434186/177221 - это работающий вариант именно для Visual Studio. Ваш ответ там тоже есть, кстати. Предлагаю переоткрыть и сделать из этого вопроса каноничный. Потому что CP1251 - это какая-то жесть.

Comment: @PashaPash: Давайте!

Comment: @Umed, это вопрос с пятью минусами, а не пример. Минусы там за последний UPD автора и к тому же Ваш charToOem и ConsoleCP там тоже есть. Видимо вы даже не удосужились нормально просмотреть скинутую ветку, увы.

Comment: @AlexKrass, виноват, исправлюсь =)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [C++ вывод "галочки" на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571405/23044)

Answer (score 108):

Для данной задачи существует множество решений. Если вам нужно **быстрое** и не обязательно универсальное решение, чтобы сильно не разбираться, прокручивайте к разделу «*Менее правильные, но пригодные решения*».

### Правильное, но сложное решение

Для начала, проблема у консоли Windows состоит в том, что её шрифты, которые стоят «по умолчанию», показывают не все символы. Вам следует сменить шрифт консоли на юникодный, это позволит работать даже на английской Windows. Если вы хотите поменять шрифт только для вашей программы, в её консоли нажмите на иконку в левом верхнем углу → Свойства → Шрифт. Если хотите поменять для всех будущих программ, то же самое, только заходите в Умолчания, а не Свойства.

Lucida Console и Consolas справляются со всем, кроме иероглифов. Если ваши консольные шрифты позволят, вы сможете вывести и `猫`, если нет, то лишь те символы, которые поддерживаются.

Дальнейшее рассмотрение касается лишь Microsoft Visual Studio. Если у вас другой компилятор, пользуйтесь предложенными на свой страх и риск, никакой гарантии нету.

Теперь, кодировка входных файлов компилятора. Компилятор Microsoft Visual Studio (по крайней мере, версии 2012 и 2013) компилирует исходники в *однобайтных* кодировках так, как будто бы они на самом деле в ANSI-кодировке, то есть для случая русской системы — CP1251. Это означает, что кодировка исходников в CP866 — неправильна. (Это важно, если вы используете `L"..."`-строки.) С другой стороны, если вы храните исходники в CP1251, то эти же исходники не будут нормально собираться на нерусской Windows. Поэтому стоит хранить исходники в Unicode (например, UTF-8).

Настроив среду, перейдём к решению собственно задачи.

Правильным решением является уйти от однобайтных кодировок, и использовать Unicode в программе. При этом вы получите правильный вывод не только кириллицы, но и поддержку всех языков (изображение отсутствующих в шрифтах символов будет отсутствовать, но вы сможете с ними работать). Для Windows это означает переход с узких строк (`char*`, `std::string`) на широкие (`wchar_t*`, `std::wstring`), и использование кодировки UTF-16 для строк.

(Ещё одна проблема, которую решает использование широких строк: узкие строки при компиляции кодируются в однобайтную кодировку используя *текущую* системную кодовую страницу, то есть, ANSI-кодировку. Если вы компилируете вашу программу на английской Windows, это приведёт к очевидным проблемам.)

Вам нужно `_setmode(_fileno(...), _O_U16TEXT);` для переключения режима консоли:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin),  _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"Unicode -- English -- Русский -- Ελληνικά -- Español." << std::endl;
    // или
    wprintf(L"%s", L"Unicode -- English -- Русский -- Ελληνικά -- Español.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Такой способ должен работать правильно с вводом и выводом, с именами файлов и перенаправлением потоков.

Важное замечание: потоки ввода-вывода находятся либо в «широком», либо в «узком» состоянии — то есть, в них выводится либо только `char*`, либо только `wchar_t*`. После первого вывода переключение не всегда возможно. Поэтому такой код:

```
cout << 5;            // или printf("%d", 5);
wcout << L"привет";   // или wprintf(L"%s", L"привет");
```

вполне может не сработать. Используйте только `wprintf`/`wcout`.

---

Если очень не хочется переходить на Unicode, и использовать однобайтную кодировку, будут возникать проблемы. Для начала, символы, не входящие в выбранную кодировку (например, для случая CP1251 — базовый английский и кириллица), работать не будут, вместо них будет вводиться и выводиться абракадабра. Кроме того, узкие строковые константы имеют ANSI-кодировку, а это значит, что кириллические строковые литералы на нерусской системе не сработают (в них будет зависимая от системной локали абракадабра). Держа в голове эти проблемы, переходим к изложению следующей серии решений.

### Менее правильные, но пригодные решения

В любом случае, поставьте юникодный шрифт в консоли. (Это первый абзац «сложного» решения.)

Убедитесь, что ваши исходники в кодировке CP 1251 (это не само собой разумеется, особенно если у вас не русская локаль Windows). Если при добавлении русских букв и сохранении Visual Studio ругается на то, что не может сохранить символы в нужной кодировке, выбирайте CP 1251.

(1) Если компьютер ваш, вы можете поменять кодовую страницу консольных программ на вашей системе. Для этого сделайте вот что:

1. Запустите Regedit.
2. На всякий пожарный экспортируйте куда-нибудь реестр (этот шаг все почему-то пропускают, так что когда всё сломается, мы вас предупреждали).
3. В разделе `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` найдите ключ `CodePage` (если нету, создайте ключ с таким названием и типом `DWORD`).
4. Установите значение по ключу (левая клавиша/изменить/Система счисления = десятичная) на 1251.
5. Не забудьте перегрузиться после изменений в реестре.

Преимущества способа: примеры из книг начнут работать «из коробки». Недостатки: смена реестра может повлечь за собой проблемы, кодировка консоли меняется глобально и перманентно — это может повлиять сломать другие программы. Плюс эффект будет только на вашем компьютере (и на других, у которых та же кодировка консоли). Плюс общие проблемы неюникодных способов.

**Примечание.** Установка глобальной кодовой страницы консоли через параметр реестра `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\CodePage` не работает в Windows 10, вместо него будет использована кодовая страница OEM - предположительно [баг в conhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47149611/8674428). При этом установка кодовой страницы консоли на уровне конкретного приложения (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\(путь к приложению)\CodePage`) работает.

(2) Вы можете поменять кодировку только вашей программы. Для этого нужно сменить кодировку консоли программным путём. Из вежливости к другим программам не забудьте потом вернуть кодировку на место!

Это делается либо при помощи вызова функций

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

в начале программы, либо про помощи вызова внешней утилиты

```
system("chcp 1251");
```

(То есть, у вас должно получиться что-то вроде

```
#include <cstdlib>  

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::system("chcp 1251");
    ...
```

или

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    ...
```

и дальше обыкновенный код программы.)

Можно обернуть эти вызовы в класс, чтобы воспользоваться плюшками автоматического управления временем жизни объектов C++.

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int chcp(unsigned codepage)
{
    // составить команду из кусочков
    std::string command("chcp ");
    command += codepage;
    // выполняем команду и возвращаем результат
    return !std::system(command.c_str());
}

// этот код будет запущен перед main
static int codepage_is_set = chcp(1251);
```

(если выполняете задание из Страуструпа можно вставить в конец заголовочного файла `std_lib_facilities.h`)

Или так:

```
#include <windows.h>

class ConsoleCP
{
    int oldin;
    int oldout;

public:
    ConsoleCP(int cp)
    {
        oldin = GetConsoleCP();
        oldout = GetConsoleOutputCP();
        SetConsoleCP(cp);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(cp);
    }

    // поскольку мы изменили свойства внешнего объекта — консоли, нам нужно
    // вернуть всё как было (если программа вылетит, пользователю не повезло)
    ~ConsoleCP()
    {
        SetConsoleCP(oldin); 
        SetConsoleOutputCP(oldout);
    }
};

// и в программе:    
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ConsoleCP cp(1251);
    std::cout << "русский текст" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если вам нужен не русский, а какой нибудь другой язык, просто замените 1251 на идентификатор нужной кодировки (список указан ниже в файле), но, разумеется, работоспособность не гарантируется.

Остались методы, которые тоже часто встречаются, приведём их для полноты.

### Методы, которые работают плохо (но могут помочь вам)

Метод, который часто рекомендуют — использование конструкции `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` У этого варианта (по крайней мере в Visual Studio 2012) гора проблем. Во-первых, проблема с *вводом* русского текста: введённый текст передаётся в программу неправильно! Нерусский текст (например, греческий) при этом вовсе не вводится с консоли. Ну и общие для всех неюникодных решений проблемы.

Ещё один метод, не использующий Unicode — использование функций `CharToOem` и `OemToChar`. Этот метод требует перекодировки каждой из строк при выводе, и (кажется) слабо поддаётся автоматизации. Он также страдает от общих для неюникодных решений недостатков. Кроме того, этот метод не будет работать (не только с константами, но и с runtime-строками!) на нерусской Windows, т. к. там OEM-кодировка не будет совпадать с CP866. В дополнение можно так же сказать что эти функции поставляются не со всеми версиями Visual Studio — например в некоторых версиях VS Express их просто нет.

---

Источники:

1. [Как выводить на экран и вводить данные типа wchar_t[]?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434173/)

   - к сожалению, автор того вопроса пользовался компилятором MinGW под Cygwin и WinXP, что делает большинство современных решений неприменимыми.
2. [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543/1988244)
3. [Conventional wisdom is retarded, aka What the @#%&* is _O_U16TEXT?](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx)
4. [What's the difference between printf(“%s”), printf(“%ls”), wprintf(“%s”), and wprintf(“%ls”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900822/276994)
5. [Русский язык в исходном коде в Dev C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/70192/10105)
6. [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @RussCoder: Э, не, не катит. А текст с `"Ελληνικά"` ваш вариант выводит?

Comment: @VladD а какое отношение греческий имеет к вопросу? Вроде бы только про русский спрашивают.

Comment: @RussCoder: Мы хотим сделать канонически правильное решение, а не то решение, которое ломает другие фичи.

Comment: @VladD это очень хорошо, но тогда наверно стоит завести отдельный вопрос типа "Как включить поддержку Unicode в консоли на C++" и к нему писать ответ. Если Вам так не нравится мой вариант, то могу его достать и собственным ответом сделать, это нужно?

Comment: @RussCoder: Взял на себя смелость отредактировать ваш текст.

Comment: Код с `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` в MinGW не компилируется, даже после добавления stdio.h (для stdin/stdout) (а ругается на не найденный `_O_U16TEXT` и wcout, про который говорит, что он не member of std::) (думаю, та же проблема возникнет у всех с DevC++)

Comment: @avp это вопрос-ответ для VisualStudio. для MinGW - нужен отдельный набор костылей :)

Comment: @PashaPash, тогда это надо указать в самом начале ответа (далеко не все (мягко говоря) будут обращать внимание на тэги вопроса).

Comment: @avp: Указал, почти в самом начале.

Comment: @VladD вроде бы тоже самое, но конечно вы уходите не туда. Человек учит C++ и хочет  простое прозрачное решение, а ему огромную статью запилили (и он ее не принял еще), и лично для меня не был очевиден процесс смены шрифта в консоли, когда я начинал учить C++, так как там нем кнопки Файл->Настройка, да и менять надо умолчания, но вы его удалили. Также я вообще не понимаю зачем менять кодировку в конструкторе и деструкторе объекта - по мне какое-то извращение, а для того, кто только учит язык по книжке  может быть немыслимо сложным (если он еще не знает ООП, да и даже если уже прочел).

Comment: @RussCoder: По поводу простого решения, замечание принято, сейчас вынесу «рецепт» наверх. По поводу того, примет ли этот ответ ОП, я не парюсь. По поводу того, как сменить шрифт в консоли — ваша рекомендация не вполне верна, нужно менять шрифт у экземпляра вашей программы, а не cmd.exe. Менять умолчания системы ради программы, наверное, неправильно.

Comment: @RussCoder: По поводу смены кодировки в конструкторе-деструкторе: во-первых, кодировку надо вернуть на место (понятно, почему?). Во-вторых, вернуть кодировку назад можно забыть, если есть ранний выход из `main`, общепринятый путь, которым C++ решает такие проблемы — RAII. Знание ООП и умение написать простой класс — кардинально разные вещи. Я вот классы писать умею, а в ООП плаваю. А ещё писать на C++ **без** классов — плохо. C++ без классов — это C.

Comment: @RussCoder: Подумал, что вы наверное правы насчёт шрифта. Вернул в ответ.

Comment: @VladD, а что будет в файле (или пайпе), если перенаправить вывод?

Comment: @VladD да идея с конструктором интересная, раньше не задумывался (точнее не знал), но что будет если не сменить кодировку назад? Она что останется навсегда?

Comment: @RussCoder: Угу, насколько я понимаю, если не вернуть, то после завершения работы приложения консоль останется с новой кодировкой. Трюк с деструктором — классная идея на самом деле, позволяет не думать о том, когда происходит выход из процедуры. Работает даже в случае exception'а. Очень рекомендую к ежедневному использованию.

Comment: @avp: Хороший вопрос! Michael Kaplan в своей статье обещает, что всё будет в порядке, но я всё же перепроверю на работе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30630/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash----).

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")  вообще не везде работает. Должно быть "ruRU.UTF-8". "Russian" Работает только на Windows, некоторых дистрибутивах Linux и то не на всех версиях\локализациях. Дажо знать что WIndows не использует Unicode по умолчанию, используется widechar - ANSI/ISO C, в том числе и для имен файлов - для них ТОЛЬКО widechar.

Comment: @Swift это вопрос/ответ именно для windows/visual c++.

Comment: Код с `_O_U16TEXT` похоже не работает в Win XP, VS2010: если написать так `std::wstring t; std::wcin>>t; std::wcout<<t;` выводятся либо вопросы, либо квадраты, в зависимости от консоли.

Comment: @Imieee это общий ответ (вроде wiki). если что-то не работает, или есть другое решение - просто допишите прямо в ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash Там много чего неправильно написано, например то что студия работает с однобайтными исходниками. С любыми она работает Только по умолчанию вы такой не создадите, надо "сохранять как". Беда только с ANSi-вариантом, так ка он полагается на текущую локаль системы. Русская версия  2010  понимала даже имена переменных на русском ( как мы ругались на случайные буквы с!).

Comment: @Swift Там не написано, что студия работает **только** с однобайтными кодировками. Там написано, что в обработке исходников в однобайтной кодировке есть некоторые особенности, и что **стоит хранить исходники в Unicode**. Читайте внимательнее :) В остальном - ответ общий, хотите что-то исправить - исправляйте.

Comment: @VladD, подсмотрел Ваше решение с обёрткой вариантов SetConsole в отдельный класс. Почему-то, не срабатывает. Класс выведен в отдельный файл. Так вот, в конструкторе, при вызове SetConsole, GetConsole возвращает 1251,а при возвращении в main, и вызове GetConsole вновь возвращает 866. Пользуюсь студией 17. Не знаете, эта проблема решается как-то? Спасибо.

Comment: @Range: Хм, странно. А можно воспроизводящий минимальный пример? И попробуйте поставить breakpoint в деструкторе, он почему-то у вас вызывается невовремя.

Comment: @VladD один момент

Comment: @VladD для удобства перенёс класс в главный файл.
https://pastebin.com/adTiSQEf
Деструктор не вызывается вообще..не понимаю, почему.

Comment: @Range лучше оформите отдельным вопросом

Comment: @PashaPash готово https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683022/Не-вызывается-деструктор-у-класса

Answer (score 5):

> Поэтому стоит хранить исходники в Unicode (например, UTF-8).

Причем сохранить следует с сигнатурой

> Ситуацию частично спасает пересохранение исходников в кодировке UTF-8 с обязательным символом BOM, без него Visual Studio начинает интерпретировать «широкие» строки с кириллицей весьма своеобразно. Однако, указав BOM (Byte Order Mark — метка порядка байтов) кодировки UTF-8 — символ, кодируемый тремя байтами 0xEF, 0xBB и 0xBF, мы получаем узнавание кодировки UTF-8 в любой системе

[Пишем по-русски в коде](https://habr.com/company/xakep/blog/257895/)

Answer (score 5):

Стоит пояснить кое-что для тех, кто ищет правильный ответ по поводу функции setlocale:

> Метод, который часто рекомендуют — использование конструкции setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); У этого варианта (по крайней мере в Visual Studio 2012) гора проблем. Во-первых, проблема с вводом русского текста: введённый текст передаётся в программу неправильно! Нерусский текст (например, греческий) при этом вовсе не вводится с консоли. Ну и общие для всех неюникодных решений проблемы.

Я добавлю по этому методу побольше информации: **Его вообще не правильно рекомендуют!**

Начнём с первого: Во втором параметре функция принимает не название страны или языка, хотя в некоторых случаях она сработает, а языковый идентификатор, согласно ISO 3166-1. Поэтому правильно и корректно указывать: "ru-RU".
Теперь второе: в документации к этой функции написано чёрным по белому: "If execution is allowed to continue, the function sets errno to EINVAL and returns NULL." Что буквально толкуется: при возникновении ошибки, функция устанавливает значение переменной errno в EINVAL и возвращает NULL.

В случае возникновения ошибки, errno всегда будет равен EINVAL, что означает: не верный аргумент. Поэтому её проверять нет смысла, а вот исполнение функции должно быть проверено. Поэтому правильный вызов функции setlocale выглядит следующим образом:

```
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru-RU") == NULL) {
        cout << "Error set locale ru-RU." << endl;
        return -1;
        // или принудительно ставим таблицу 1251 через SetConsoleCP.
        // выше пример есть. И не забываем проверять результат SetConsoleCP
        // Если ошибка возникла, то код ошибки смотрим через GetLastError.
}
```

И не забывайте, что setlocale устанавливает локальную таблицу только для ANSI кодировки, поэтому и не будут отображаться греческие, испанские, китайские и даже японские знаки. 
Для русского языка это будет таблица номер 1251.

И важно: почему эта функция является надёжней, нежели прямая установка таблицы символов через SetConsoleCP, ибо потому, что она переключает все внутренние надстройки именно для раскладки под язык. Начиная от стандарта отображения даты, заканчивая знаками разделителя.

И да, не стоит устанавливать языковый указатель виде "ru", так как в зависимости от сборки самой ось и имеющихся языковых пакетов, может установиться ru-BY, ru-UA, ru-MO и другие языковые стандарты, значительно отличающиеся от ru-RU. И категорично нельзя указывать "Russia", "Russian", "Russian Federation" (да, такую вакханалию уже встречал пару раз). Хотя функция производит проверку и по названию региона, не всегда в таблице локализации это указано, или может быть указано "Россия" или "Русский" уже на нашей раскладке. Это и есть основная ошибка, из-за которой функция setlocale зачастую отказывается работать.

И да, для приложения, **работающего в режиме юникогда**, стоит использовать функцию **_wsetlocale**. Она идентична, и также устанавливает базовые настройки для локализации. Кроме того, если проект приложения в Visual Studio настроен в режим юникода, то и будет работать только _wsetlocale, так как setlocale, по документации, не приспособлена к работе с юникодом вообще никак.

**UPD.**

---

Совсем забыл указать, что функция setlocale и _wsetlocale, в случае успеха вернёт именно идентификатор региона. То есть, в нашем случае строку "ru_RU\0".

Comment: функции setlocale и _wsetlocale делают абсолютно одно и то же и никак не связаны с режимом Unicode в проекте. Единственное их отличие - тип аргумента. `_wsetlocale is a wide-character version of setlocale; the locale argument and return value of _wsetlocale are wide-character strings. _wsetlocale and setlocale behave identically otherwise.` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2015

Comment: Что касается `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")`, этот вариант, хоть и является нерекомендуемым, вполне допустим и соответствует документации. `The locale argument can take a locale name, a language string, a language string and country/region code, a code page, or a language string, country/region code, and code page.` Строка "Russian" перечислена как имя языка в спецификации https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c Ни от какой раскладки она не зависит.

Answer (score 4):

Для Clion:

Cygwin - при установке в выборе пакетов нужно найти и отметить всякие `cmake`, `GDB` и прочие, кем-нибудь рекомендуемые к установке.

> Сlion - File - Settings - Editor - File Encodings: IDE Encoding,
>   Project Encoding, `main.cpp` (Ваш исполняемый файл) - UTF-8, Default
>   encoding for properties files - IBM866
>
> В окне редактора внизу - UTF-8.

Включить в проект заголовочный файл `Windows.h`

```
SetConsoleCP(866); SetConsoleOutputCP(866);
```

Comment: Сам проверял хоть. Не работает.

Comment: @ilw У меня все работает.

Answer (score 0):

#### Попробуйте это

> Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode program и меняем на русский

вариант на русифицированной Windows:

> Панель управления > Часы, язык и регион > Региональные стандарты (Регион) > Дополнительно > Изменить язык системы..  и меняем на русский