# Как в visual studio поставить по умолчанию кодировку DOS-866

Tags: visual-studio, кодировка

К примеру, в Notepad++ в настройках можно выбрать кодировку по умолчанию.
Когда я создаю новый файл то кодировка у него та, что я выбрал по умолчанию.

Так, вот можно ли в Visual Studio выставить кодировку по умолчанию скажем DOS-866? Я не хочу пользоваться `Setlocale` и другими похожими функциями. Или мне придется постоянно менять вручную или пользоваться функциями?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русский язык в консоли](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: Можно, но компиляция всё равно будет считать, что у вас CP1251. Смотрите сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105

Comment: Я бы не называл это полным дубликатом. Связь-то не очевидна...

Comment: Это не дубликат. Вопрос по настройке VS.

Comment: @VladD, вопрос вполне конкретный. Цель та же, но вопрос совсем другой.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, такой настройки в Visual Studio нет. Можно лишь попросить студию сохранять исходники в UTF-8, если она не может сохранить какой-то символ в текущей кодовой странице.
`Options->Environment->Documents-> Save documents as Unicode...`
Никакого другого автоматического метода не существует. Все остальные методы подразумевают работу с каждый файлом в отдельности.

Comment: Да-а... 2019 год, одна из самых мощных сред разработки, и нет элементарной возможности, жизненно необходимой для работы с legacy code.