# Как передать данные в MySQL в UTF8 на Visual C++

Tags: c++, mysql, utf-8

Добрый вечер. Возникла проблема при записи в бд mysql данных из консольной программы, написанной на Visual C++.
Суть в следующем. Я получаю данные в массив. Там есть значения на английском языке и на русском. Потом эти значения записываю в таблицу mysql. Все поля таблицы имеют кодировку utf8_general_ci
Английские значения пишутся без искажений, а вот с русскими беда - в базу все записывается иероглифами. Я понимаю, что изначально в Windows все хранится в 1251 кодировке. Нужно как-то  это переконвертировать в UTF8. Ничего толкового, что помогло не нашел. Подскажите плиз как решить данную проблему?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Укажите базе, что символы в кодировке utf-8. Никогда не используйте ужас наподобие cp1251 или там koi8-r.

Comment: Если указываю , что SET NAMES utf8 , то вместо русских значений, пусто. С удовольствием бы не использовал этот ужас, но мне данные приходят в этой кодировке.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, я предостерёг бы от работы с консолью, если это только не программа для разработчиков. Если вы пишете программу для реальных клиентов — сделайте UI.

Теперь, если вы всё же хотите вводить многоязычный текст в консольную программу, вам лучше всего перейти на `wstring`, как [описано в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105).

Остаётся вопрос конвертации `wstring` в UTF-8. Для этого можно, например, использовать WinAPI-функцию [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) с кодовой страницей `CP_UTF8`.

Ещё один вариант конвертации `wstring` в UTF-8 такой (одолжено из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809553/276994)):

```
wstring wstr = L"ля ля ля-ля-ля ля-ля-ля-ля-ля"; // ввод пользователя

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> wconv;
std::string utf8str = wconv.to_bytes(wstr);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать как вы написали

Comment: @Петр: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Comment: ещё видел в рабочем проекте вариант просто перекодировать вручную, вполне рабочий вариант, гуглится по запросу `cp2utf()`

Comment: @YuriyOrlov: Не, это плохой вариант. Одноязычным кодировкам типа cp1251 не место в нашей вселенной в 2015 году.