# setw задаёт разную ширину поля вывода строк

Tags: c++, строки, потоки-данных

Привет!
Есть таблица некоторых строковых переменных (`string`). Необходимо эту таблицу вывести в адекватном форматированном виде. Проблема заключается в том, что при использовании манипулятора `setw ()` строки, разные по длине, занимают разную ширину поля, а не фиксированную.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string one = "Один", two = "Два", eight = "Восемь";
  cout << setw (10) << one <<endl;
  cout << setw (10) << two <<endl;
  cout << setw (10) << eight <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
  один
   два
восемь
```

Что выходит на самом деле:

```
  один
    два
восемь
```

Собственно вопрос - почему так? И как всё таки можно выводить строки выровненными - одну под другой?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эх. Судя по всему, это проблемы интернационализации и utf-8.

Дело в том, что C++ не знает об utf-8, и считает ширину поля в байтах, а не в реальных символах. А для utf-8 количество байт не равно количеству символов. Обратите внимание, что у вас ширина поля получилась не 10, а меньше — текст `"Один"` в utf-8 занимает больше четырёх байт, поэтому количество недостающих до 10 байт меньше.

Попробуйте перейти на широкие строки:

```
wstring one = L"Один", two = L"Два", eight = L"Восемь";
wcout << setw (10) << one << endl;
wcout << setw (10) << two << endl;
wcout << setw (10) << eight << endl;
```

Если вы работаете под Windows, вам придётся [прибегнуть к небольшой акробатике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105), чтобы заставить консоль правильно понимать широкие строки. Под линуксом, кажется, достаточно в начале программы применить заклинание

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

Заметьте, что консольный ввод/вывод приложения должен быть либо полностью «узкий», либо полностью «широкий»: переключиться после первого выведенного символа уже нельзя.

Comment: На широких строках вывод действительно происходит форматированным, но состоит усключительно из вопросительных знаков

Comment: Хм. А какая ОС? И какой компилятор?

Comment: Kubuntu (14.04), g++

Comment: И gcc? Я-то думал, у линукса этих проблем мету :-\

Comment: Сейчас гляну, что можно сделать.

Comment: @TheCat: А если добавить в начало программы `setlocale (LC_ALL,"");`?

Comment: Так вот где собака зарыта. setlocale я писал всегда, но вторым аргументом я указывал не пустые кавычки, а совал туда "rus" локаль, так как считал, что "" принимает локаль системную и не сможет мне помочь. Спасибо за то, что ткнули носом (=

Comment: @TheCat: То есть, сработало? Аргумент в локали означает «системная локаль вот такая». А пустая строка означает «само выясняй, я не знаю точно».

Comment: Да, сработало.  
Кстати, проблем с utf-8 изначально действительно не было. Но через некоторое время, с приходом некоторого обновления или с приходом мною установленной библиотеки, появились проблемы с кириллицей в написанном мною коде. Так что, с gnu компилятором, я думаю, всё нормально, чего не скажешь о моих руках (=

Comment: @TheCat: ... или со стандартом :-\ Он мог измениться, а gcc-то что, обязан поддерживать.