# отладочная консоль и windows 10

Tags: c++, консоль, windows-10

Раньше, когда я не перешел на "вин 10", я всегда использовал в своих программах вот такой простенький код для создания консоли в не консольных приложениях(код работал в вин 7,8,8.1):

```
void createConsole()
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;
    FILE *fp;
    AllocConsole();
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
}
```

Выводил в консоль данные с помощью обычного "printf", далее я перешел на вин 10 и испробовал скомпилировать свой проект на этой платформе - со старым кодом. К моему удивлению в не консольном приложении нечего в консоль не вывелось, а в консольном посредством функции "printf" вывелось - но я не смог вывести русский шрифт не смотря на то, что я задал кириллицу "setlocale(0, "Russian");". Далее погуглив на счет кодировки я все же смог выставить "русскую кодировку" в консольном приложении:

```
//Устанавливаем русский язык
    if (system("chcp 1251")) {
        message("Не удалось установить русский язык в консоле!");
    }

    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

Проблема заключалась в следующем, мне консоль очень нужна в "не консольном" приложении и погуглив я нашел другой код для создания и вывода данных в консоль на "msdn":

```
HANDLE handle;
void createConsole(){
AllocConsole();
handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
}

bool write(std::string description, ...)
{
    char buf[1024];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    va_list vaList;
    va_start(vaList, description);
    vsprintf_s(buf, (description + "\n").c_str(), vaList);
    va_end(vaList);

    if (WriteConsoleA(handle, buf, strlen(buf), 0, 0) == 0) {

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Консоль работает- все данные выводятся - но я не могу выводить русские символы в консоль, даже этот код не помогает и не могу выводить информацию через "printf":

```
//Устанавливаем русский язык
        if (system("chcp 1251")) {
            message("Не удалось установить русский язык в консоле!");
        }

        SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

Собственно вопросы:

- Почему в вин 10 перестал работать старый код для создания консоли?
- Почему я не могу выводить кириллицу в новую консоль и может ли это зависеть от языкового пакета установленного на мою винду 10?
- Почему не могу выводить данные через printf в не консольном приложении?

Так как я начинающий программист, хотелось услышать мнение профи о том нужна ли вообще отладочная консоль и если нет то что тогда используют профи или может я не правильно работаю с консолью, как вообще нужно делать правильно и грамотно?

Comment: Может быть, пора уже на Юникод переходить? XXI век на дворе.

Comment: В чем преимущество и особенности?

Comment: В том, что поддерживаются абсолютно все символы во всех кодировках, а не только 255 символов из любимой кодировки.

Comment: Попробовал вывести русский текст в юникоде через "wprintf" - та же самая ерунда что и с printf в не консольном приложении - вообще нечего не выводит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О том как выводить русский текст в консоль написано тут - [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8).

Однако, судя по всему Вы используете консоль только для логов. В Windows для этого есть система отладочного вывода, а именно функция [`OutputDebugStringW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), вывод которой можно смотреть в отладчике, или в утилите [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx).

Способ, который используется в промышленном программировании - это библиотеки логов. Развитые системы логирования [поддерживают различные приемники логов](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html), в т.ч. `stdout/stderr` и `OutputDebugString`.

Comment: Да я использую консоль исключительно для логов и вывода результатов вычислений переменных. На счет  OutputDebugStringW - мне лично кажется что это не удобно все же можно поставить брейк поинт и так же посмотреть все результаты. А на счет логгирования с помощью boost- все просто - я еще не дошел до изучения boost, но все же интересно почему в вин 10 появились проблемы с консолью?