# Unicode и char. Подскажите как корректно заменить char на wchar_t?

Tags: c++, linux, unicode

Есть игра "Виселица", которая написана для работы только с английскими символами. Хочу добавить русские слова. Не получается заменить тип char в программе на другие, чтобы была возможность ввода и обработки символов кириллицы.

```
char guess;
```

Поискав похожие темы, понял что, символы Unicode кодируются двумя байтами, а тип char может помещать один. Поэтому в игре вместо кириллицы отображаются ромбы со знаками вопросов.
Подскажите, как правильно заменить char на wchar_t, чтобы компилятор не выдавал ошибку в строках сравнения THE_WORD[i] == guess и soFar[i] = guess;

```
// update soFar to include newly guessed letter
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
{
    if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
    {
        soFar[i] = guess;
    }
}
```

Система Ubuntu 14.04, компилятор GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit
Qt Creator 3.6.0 Based on Qt 5.5.1

Вот весь код

```
// Hangman
// The classic game of hangman

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // set-up
    const int MAX_WRONG = 8;  // maximum number of incorrect guesses allowed

    vector<string> words;  // collection of possible words to guess
    words.push_back("монитор");
    words.push_back("телескоп");
    words.push_back("смартфон");

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end());
    const string THE_WORD = words[0];            // word to guess
    int wrong = 0;                               // number of incorrect guesses
    string soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '*');          // word guessed so far
    string used = "";                            // letters already guessed

    cout << "Welcome to Hangman.  Good luck!\n";

    // main loop
    while ((wrong < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD))
    {
        cout << "\n\nYou have " << (MAX_WRONG - wrong);
        cout << " incorrect guesses left.\n";
        cout << "\nYou've used the following letters:\n" << used << endl;
        cout << "\nSo far, the word is:\n" << soFar << endl;

        char guess;
        cout << "\n\nEnter your guess: ";
        cin >> guess;

        while (used.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "\nYou've already guessed " << guess << endl;
            cout << "Enter your guess: ";
            cin >> guess;                
        }

        used += guess;

        if (THE_WORD.find(guess) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "That's right! " << guess << " is in the word.\n";

            // update soFar to include newly guessed letter
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i)
            {
                if (THE_WORD[i] == guess)
                {
                    soFar[i] = guess;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, " << guess << " isn't in the word.\n";
            ++wrong;
        }
    }

    // shut down
    if (wrong == MAX_WRONG)
        cout << "\nYou've been hanged!";
    else
        cout << "\nYou guessed it!";

    cout << "\nThe word was " << THE_WORD << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: тип char*(или std::string) можно использовать для хранения utf-8, тип char16_t* для строк UCS2(UTF16), char32_t для UTF-32. Но дальше этого Вы не пойдёте, нет функций по работе со строкой, как со строкой. Это всё остаётся массивом объектов определённого типа. Можете почитать начала моей [статьи](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/12/29/various_literals.aspx). Там как раз идёт разговор о положении дел с юникодом в C++

Comment: `wchar_t` — правильный путь. Вот вам небольшой гайд по русификации консольных программ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105 Кроме того, замените везде `char` на `wchar_t`, `string` на `wstring`, константы типа `"abc"` на константы типа `L"абв"`, `cin`/`cout`/`cerr` на `wcin`/`wcout`/`wcerr`.

Comment: Вот [тут](http://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW) и [тут](http://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL) есть разные функции для работы с utf-8 даже без настройки locale. А вообще-то в консоли Ubuntu можно выбрать однобайтную кодировку русского языка (например, windows-1251) и перевести (как Вам советовали в уже удаленном ответе) программу в эту кодировку (можно использовать команду [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv))

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34515/discussion-on-question-by-did-mazay-unicode--char----).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Русский язык в консоли](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, благодаря помощи участников сайта: @gbg ,@avp, @Abyx, @ixSci и особенно @VladD удалось решить вопрос мультиязычности программы 'Виселица'.
Привожу полный код решения и комментарий к нему.

```
// Система Ubuntu 14.04, компилятор GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit
// Qt Creator 3.6.0 Based on Qt 5.5.1

// Классическая игра 'Виселица'
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>   // заголовочный файл настройки локализации
                    // содержит функции для работы с локализацией программы.
                    // Если не включить этот файл и не использовать функцию locale, то
                    // русские надписи будут выводиться в виде нечитабельных иероглифов

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    locale::global(locale("")); // ф-ция для установки локали
                                // http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global

    // первоначальные настройки
    const int MAX_WRONG = 8;    // максимальное количество попыток
    vector<wstring> words;      // коллекция слов для отгадывания
    words.push_back(L"монитор");
    words.push_back(L"терминал");
    words.push_back(L"смартфон");

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));  // засев поля случайных чисел
    random_shuffle(words.begin(), words.end()); // перемешивание слов
    const wstring THE_WORD = words[0];          // слово для отгадывания
    int wrong = 0;                              // количество неправильных попыток
    wstring soFar(THE_WORD.size(), '*');        // угадываемое слово на данный момент
    wstring used = L"";                         // использованные буквы
    wcout << L"Добро пожаловать в 'Виселицу'. Удачи!\n";

    // основная игра
    while ((wrong < MAX_WRONG) && (soFar != THE_WORD)) {
        wcout << L"\nУ Вас остается " << (MAX_WRONG - wrong) << L" попыток.\n";
        wcout << L"\nВы использовали следующие буквы:\n" << used << "\n";
        wcout << L"\nПока слово:\n" << soFar << "\n";

        wchar_t guess;
        wcout << L"\n\nВведите букву: ";
        wcin >> guess;

        while (used.find(guess) != wstring::npos) {
            wcout << L"\nВы уже называли букву '" << guess << "'\n";
            wcin >> guess;
        }
        used += guess;
        if (THE_WORD.find(guess) != wstring::npos) {
            wcout << L"Верно! '" << guess << L"' есть в слове.\n";

            // обновляем слово угаданными буквами
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < THE_WORD.length(); ++i) {
                if (THE_WORD[i] == guess) {
                    soFar[i] = guess;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
        wcout << L"Извините, буквы '" << guess << L"' нет в слове.\n";
        ++wrong;
        }
    }

    // конец игры
    if (wrong == MAX_WRONG) {
        wcout << L"\nВас повесили!";
    }
    else {
        wcout << L"\nВы угадали!";
    }
    wcout << L"\nСлово было '" << THE_WORD << L"'\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Итак, основные изменения в программе, чтобы корректно отображались и обрабатывались символы кириллицы.
1 - добавить заголовочный файл locale
2 - использовать функцию установки локали locale::global(locale(""));
3 - Заменить везде char на wchar_t, string на wstring, cin на wcin, cout на wcout (и главное, то что я немного упускал из виду,- строку на вывод отправлять не просто "строка", а L"строка" !!!)
Вот и весь секрет работы с Юникодом в С++
Все полезные замечания обязательно учту.

Comment: Только не забудьте, что система должна быть правильно локализована (хотя и `en_US.UTF-8` (или другая utf-locale тоже сойдет). В противном случае `locale("")` не сможет установить правильные таблицы трансляции для перевода символов между utf-8 (консоль (точнее, эмулятор терминала)) и внутренним представлением `w_char` (ucs-32).

Comment: @avp: эту информацию нужно добавить, в ответ, или достаточно, что она есть в вашем комментарии?

Comment: IMHO тут комментария достаточно. Если хотите, можете поместить эту инфу в свой ответ.

Comment: @avp: тогда все оставляем как есть.