# Кириллица в CharUnion.UnicodeChar

Tags: c#, winapi, unicode, char

Кратко о проблеме: 
Делаю вывод в консоль через WINAPI **WriteConsoleOutput**. Все работает просто прекрасно, кроме кириллицы. Например, запись символа '\u0430' вместо ожидаемой 'а' дает в консоли '0' ('\u0030').

```
Console.WriteLine('\u0430');
```

Работает корректно.

Ниже - части кода и разъяснения.

Декларация DLLImport выглядит так:

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string fileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare,
        IntPtr securityAttributes,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags,
        IntPtr template);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteConsoleOutput(
      SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
      CharInfo[] lpBuffer,
      Coord dwBufferSize,
      Coord dwBufferCoord,
      ref SmallRect lpWriteRegion);
```

CharSet не задан на WriteConsoleOutput потому что он не решает проблему, но ко всему прочему ещё и меняет Ascii символы на кашу. Та же ситуация с CharSet для CreateFile. 
Использовать **WriteConsoleOutputW** так же пробовал и с тем же результатом.

Далее структуры, с помощью которых формируется lpBuffer для передачи в WriteConsoleOutput:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CharUnion
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] public char UnicodeChar;
  [FieldOffset(0)] public byte AsciiChar;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CharInfo
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] public CharUnion Char;
  [FieldOffset(2)] public short Attributes;
}
```

Создание SafeFileHandle выглядит следующим образом:

```
SafeFileHandle Handle = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

А вот пример того, заполняется сам буфер, который мы собираемся передавать в функцию:

```
CharInfo[] buffer = new CharInfo[10];
buffer[1].Char.UnicodeChar = '\u0430';
```

Буду рад помощи с этим, т.к. у самого идеи закончились и поиск ничего не дал.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8?lq=1

Comment: @Alexis спасибо,ознакомился с ответом по ссылке,но не уверен,что это мой случай,в конце концов у меня нет проблем с выводом кириллицы в принципе, русский язык в консоли у меня отображается без проблем до тех пор,пока я не использую конкретно функцию writeconsoleoutput. Пожалуйста,поправьте,если я не прав

Comment: Так надо использовать WriteConsoleOutputW  с юникодом.