# Как обновлять консоль в одном и том же месте без перезагрузки экрана?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Подскажите как можно писать в консоль в тоже место асинхронно, как это делает докер на следующем скрине:

[image]

Comment: Функциями для работы с консолью WriteConsoleOutput и их семейством. Вбейте в поиск WriteConsoleOutput с#

Comment: На so вот есть наброски https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499668/%d0%9a%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-charunion-unicodechar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Запоминаете текущие координаты курсора в консоли, потом устанавливаете их же.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("1 Downloading: ");
    var left1 = Console.CursorLeft;
    var top1 = Console.CursorTop;

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("2 Downloading: ");
    var left2 = Console.CursorLeft;
    var top2 = Console.CursorTop;

    Console.CursorVisible = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left1, top1);
        Console.Write(i + " MB");

        Console.SetCursorPosition(left2, top2);
        Console.Write(i * 2 + " MB");

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Потрясающе! это какая то магия! Спасибо!)