# Сравнивание массивов символов с++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char *empty[1];
    cout << "Введите ваше имя:";
    cin >> *empty;

    char *mas[1] = { "Роман" };



    if (*empty == *mas)
    {
        cout << "Красава братуха, го прожить\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Петух, качай вижуалку\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Работа программы прекращается, при введении чего-либо в консоль. Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Ну, вы не выделяете память под массив, вам ещё повезло, что вылетело.

Comment: Что, по-вашему, делает код `char *empty[1];`?

Comment: Создает пустой массив, разве не так?
Не могли бы вы показать, как видите программу, вы?

Comment: Окей, это создаёт массив неинициализированных указателей на `char`. Он не пустой, в нём один элемент. Теперь, `*empty` есть первый (ну то есть нулевой) неинициализированный указатель. `cin >> *empty` читает ввод пользователя в область памяти по неинициализированному указателю — «на кого бог пошлёт». Это скорее всего затрёт чужую память.

Comment: Кроме того, сравнение строк и сравнение указателей на `char` кардинально разные вещи. Сравнение указателей проверяет равенство указателей :) а не текста, который возможно лежит по этим указателям. Но это не причина падения — до этого кода программа просто не доходит.

Comment: Как тогда правильно выполнить программу, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разберем построчно.

```
char *empty[1];
```

Объявлен массив из одного указателя. `empty[0]` - единственный элемент, указывает в совершенно случайное место, не будучи инициализирован.

```
cin >> *empty;
```

`empty` - по сути, указатель на первый элемент массива. `*empty` - разыменованный первый элемент массива, то же, что и `empty[0]` - т.е. указатель куда-то. Неизвестно куда. И вы в это неизвестно куда пишете.
Но когда пишешь неизвестно куда, обычно случается неизвестно что...

Но даже если бы туда можно было написать, то сравнение

```
(*empty == *mas)
```

никогда бы не было корректным - потому что вы сравниваете не содержимое строк, а указатели. А вероятность, что случайно в `empty[0]` будет то же значение, что и в `mas[0]` - исчезающе мала.

Вы должны приготовить место для записи, например,

```
char empty[100];
```

или можно динамически выделить память

```
char * empty = new char[100];
```

и потом писать в него

```
cin >> empty;
```

Ну, и сравнивать специальными функциями - например, `strcmp`. (О `string` пока говорить, как я понимаю, рано.)

Comment: ... или лучше, раз уж тег [tag:c++], пользоваться человеческими строками (`std::string`).

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, буду переделывать.

Comment: `char * empty; cin >> empty;` - ничем не отличается от [gets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets). А это очень и очень плохо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А этот вопрос со времени задания вопроса (2016 год, заметим :)) уже закрыт — нет такой возможности больше, что с `gets`, что с `cin>>`...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, в C++ принято не заморачиваться с ручным управлением памятью, а использовать `std::string` и его аналоги. При этом в качестве бонуса и операция сравнения будет работать интуитивно понятным образом.

Затем, для корректной русификации нужно перейти от узких к широким строкам. Для этого можно воспользоваться [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105), и взять оттуда скелет программы.

Получится вот что:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    // заклинания для поддержки Unicode консолью
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    wstring empty;
    wcout << L"Введите ваше имя: ";
    wcin >> empty;

    wstring mas =  L"Роман" ;

    if (empty == mas)
    {
        wcout << L"Красава братуха, го прожить\n";
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << L"Петух, качай вижуалку\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Убедитесь, что вы сохраняете файл в кодировке Unicode, а не CP1251.