# Как сменить таблицу символов в C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня в C++ по умолчанию стоит *ASCII*. Как мне переключить кодовую страницу на *Unicode*, чтобы cout мог отображать символы из данной таблицы по их универсальным именам вида `'\uXXXX'`? Символы должны отображаться в консоли.

Comment: где именно вы хотите отображать символы? В среде, в консоли, в приложении, где-то еще?

Comment: Гляньте ещё сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105

Answer (score 3):

Нашел решение: необходимо работать с символами и строками *Unicode* так, как с данными типа `wchar_t`, т.е. использовать wcout вместо `cout`, предваряя символьные константы и строки префиксом `L`. Пример: `wcout << L"\u00f5\n\n";` - печатает символ `i` с двумя точками.

Comment: и зачем здесь эта цитата из книжки для типа "C++ для чайников"