# Вопросы по кодировке

Tags: c++, кодировка

Пусть у нас есть документ `code.cpp`, который был сохранен в кодировке `windows-1251`:

```
//.......header
char z = 172
std::cout<< z << std::endl; // выведет ¬
//.......
```

Вывело то, что мы и ожидали, тащемто. Кодировка такая и символ ему соответствует, но с другой стороны, будь мы на Windows, то консоль будет работать с кодировкой `OEM (Кодировка 866)`, а в этой кодировке число 172 обозначает совсем другой символ, а именно `м`.

Как же так получается? Если воспроизводит консоль результат, то разве не должна она это в своей кодировке отобразить?

Comment: А если подумать?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ничего не приходит в голову, вот поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Консоль получает не символ `м`, а байт с кодом 172. Она не перекодирует это сама, т. к. не знает ничего о кодировке, в которой этот байт интерпретируется программой. Задача конвертации лежит на рантайм-библиотеке (которая скорее всего ленится).

Comment: @ДмитрийТрапов: Гляньте сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105

Comment: @VladD вот, то что нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только сейчас осознал всю глупость вопроса. Я только ввел в заблуждение. Выводились одинаковые символы ровно по тому, потому что у меня `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")` было объявлено в коде. А так консоль воспроизводит ровно `OEM 866 кодировку`.

Answer (score 3):

Есть число `172`. В консоли показывается символ с кодов 172. Независимо от того, какая сейчас кодировка. Код один и тот же, а символ разный. Всё логично.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что символ один и тот же, хотя кодировка консоли другая. В этом вопрос-то и заключался.

Comment: @ДмитрийТрапов, не понял. Так что выводится-то?

Comment: В консоли стоит кодировка `OEM 866`, в которой код 172 означает другой символ. А выводится в консоли символ для кодировки `win1251`.

Comment: @ДмитрийТрапов, а это странно. У меня никогда так не работало. А какой компилятор?

Comment: MinGW, который шел вместе с Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [SetConsoleOutputCP()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686036(v=vs.85).aspx) и выводите всё что вам нужно. Но есть нюанс: в целевой системе может не оказаться шрифтов с символами нужной CodePage.