# Проблемы с выводом на русском языке

Tags: c++

Никто не подскажет в чем проблема:

using namespace std;

```
int main(){

    cout<<"Привет мир!"<<endl;
    return 0;

    cin.get();
}
```

Вроде бы все правильно, а на консоли выводятся какие-то иероглифы вместо русских букв(Dev C++ и CodeBlocks), в чём проблема?

Comment: C кодировкой тут уже есть несколько вопросов-ответов, вы их смотрели?

Comment: Вот например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662983/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-c

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514624/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема тут с кодировкой

```
int main() {
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

   cout<<"Привет мир!"<<endl;
   return 0;

   cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо братан!