# Консоль выводит абракадабру, в нетбинс по умолчанию стоит кодировка utf-8 без бом

Tags: c++, локаль

В выводе все показывается. Если вручную переставить из кодировки по умолчанию в ANSI, а потом еще и блокнотом перекодировать туда же, то: в редакторе абракадабра, в консоли порядок, в ANSI выводит нормально.

Собственно, вопрос: есть ли варианты выводить именно в UTF-8? Ибо танцы с бубном чего-то не особо веселят. Вариант `setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF-8"//"","utf-8");` не помог.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    std::cout << "РАБОТАЙ!\n";
    int stop;
    std::cin >> stop;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Windows? Виндоконсоль не очень дружит с UTF-8.

Comment: Вот аналогичный вопрос о Visual Studio, с хорошими шансами будет полезен и вам: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105

Comment: @VladD Что ж спасибо будем маятся