# не работает русская локаль C++

Tags: c++

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    char name[20];  
    printf("Введите ваше имя: \n");
    scanf("%20s", &name);
    printf("Привет %20s!\n", name);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Вывод программы]

Comment: Какой компилятор/ОС?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010. Windows 8. последний раз программировал в мае - работало.

Comment: Тогда это дубликат, вам сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105

Comment: Теперь вылетает вот эта ошибка - http://prntscr.com/bs15pw http://prntscr.com/bs15xj

Comment: Ещё бы, вы используете `wscanf` с `wstring`. И я бы на его месте вылетал. Используйте `wcin >>`.

Comment: а что делать если мне нужно сишный код написать?

Comment: Используйте `wchar_t[]` и `wscanf`. Только ради бога, ограничьте количество вводимых символов, иначе получите расстрел памяти. // Впрочем, у вас в коде так и есть. (Но не уверен насчёт финального нуля, перепроверьте, не нужно ли заводить буфер на 1 символ больше.)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bs1myf я уже не знаю как ввести русский символ, раньше при подключении локали просто работало

Comment: Проблему решил, спасибо. Решается так:  SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
 setlocale(0, "rus"); Правда не особо понял почему.

Comment: Странно. Перепроверил, у меня сработало: http://pastebin.com/ZFJikz0b, http://i.stack.imgur.com/orgJt.png. Но у меня Visual Studio 2015. Рецепты из ответа проверял на 2012 и 2013, всё работало.

Comment: Подождите, а если удалить из вашего кода `setlocale`? Оно явно всё портит, уводит из Unicode в cp1251.

Comment: если удалить то опять каракули

Comment: Вы пробовали именно такой код: http://pastebin.com/ZFJikz0b? Без добавлений/убавлений? Без `setlocale`? И файл сохранили как UTF-8?

Comment: да выводит квадратики