# Правильный вывод степени

Tags: c++, winapi

Как в окне правильно вывести степени, т.е. не x^2, а чтобы двойка находилась выше?

Comment: Смотря от кодировки консоли. В европейских кодировках есть символ ², например. В CP 1251 нету. Если консоль (и её шрифт) поддерживают Unicode, см. сюда: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала, вам нужно настроить правильный вывод Unicode. Как это делать, описано в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105).

Имея вывод в Unicode, легко подсмотреть номера юникодных символов, и написать функцию перекодировки. Например, такую:

```
wchar_t digitToSuperscript(unsigned int digit)
{
    if (digit >= 10)
        throw std::out_of_range("digit");
    switch (digit)
    {
    case 1: return 0x00B9;
    case 2: return 0x00B2;
    case 3: return 0x00B3;
    default: return 0x2070 + digit;
    }
}
```

(Ну или если вам больше нравится, lookup в таблице из 10 элементов.)

Пробуем:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdexcept>

wchar_t digitToSuperscript(unsigned int digit)
{
    if (digit >= 10)
        throw std::out_of_range("digit");
    switch (digit)
    {
    case 1:
        return 0x00B9;
    case 2:
        return 0x00B2;
    case 3:
        return 0x00B3;
    default:
        return 0x2070 + digit;
    }
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"x";
    for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++)
        std::wcout << digitToSuperscript(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image: картинка]

Comment: А больших 9 степеней нет? Или просто другие коды?

Comment: @genius: Нет, выводите по одной цифре.