# Подскажите, почему выводится только второе значение и то только первые два?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, бинарное-дерево

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой неприятностью как вывод из файла в программу данных. По замыслу собираюсь сделать нечто вроде интерактивного словаря. Считываю значения из файла `text1.txt`вот он сам:

```
  1   Salt                      Соль
  2   Apple                     Яблоко
  3   Second                    Второй
  4   Sand                      Песок
```

но получаю только это
[image: само консольное окно]

Хотя на дебаге отображает только первую строчку и то не в консольном окне. Хочется узнать почему?

Файл `Классы_вариант_2.cpp`(главный)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Binary_tree.h"

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("color 0A");
    wifstream file;//объявляю объект класса wifstream
    wcout.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));// для wchat_t и wchar_t чтобы  
    wcin.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));//отображались русские символы
    file.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));//c возможностью помещение и извлечения
    // в и из потока. 
    Dictionary *d = NULL;// объявляю объекты класса Dictionary 
    Dictionary *root = NULL;// и присваиваю нулевое значение 
    bool flag = true;// позволяет пройти только в метод add_root
    bool flag_for_buf = true;// возможность переключения чтения как из файла так с клавиатуры
    char filename[] = "text1.txt";
    wchar_t buf[l_buf + 1];

    file.open(filename);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        wcout << L"Файл не найден!" << endl;
       _getch();
        return 1;
    }
    while (file.getline(buf, l_buf))//читает до конца строки в файле пока не произойдет перенос на другую строчку и так пока не завершится файл(файл завершен корректно и заканчивается ровно на окончании последнего слова)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            root = d->add_root(d, buf, flag, flag_for_buf);
            d = root;
            flag = false;
        }
        else
            root->search_and_add_second(root, buf, flag_for_buf);
    }
    //file.close();
    root->print_tree(d,0);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Файл `Binary_tree.h`

```
pragma once
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>

using std::wcout;
using std::wcin;
using std::endl;
using std::locale;
using std::wifstream;
using std::wofstream;
using std::ios;

const int l_Eng_words = 25;
const int l_Rus_words = 25;
const int l_key = 4;
const int l_buf = l_Eng_words + l_Rus_words + l_key;

enum Dir//буду в дальнейшем использовать
{
     LEFT,RIGHT
};


class Dictionary
{
public:

    Dictionary() :key(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) 
    {
        std::cout << endl << "Construktor is working..." << endl;
        Eng_word = new wchar_t[25];
        Rus_word = new wchar_t[25];
    }
    ~Dictionary()
    {
        std::cout << endl << " Destructor is working..." << endl;
        delete[] Eng_word;
        delete[] Rus_word;
    }
    void print_tree(Dictionary*, int);
    Dictionary *add_root(Dictionary*,wchar_t*,bool,bool);
    Dictionary *search_and_add_second(Dictionary*, const wchar_t*,bool);
    //Dictionary *searach_for_delete(Dictionary*,Dictionary*&,Dir&)const;
    //Dictionary *delete_word(Dictionary*, Dictionary*, Dictionary*,Dir)const;

private:
    wint_t key;
    wchar_t* Eng_word;
    wchar_t* Rus_word;
    Dictionary *left, *right;
};

#endif // !FILENAME_H
```

и файл `Binary_tree.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Binary_tree.h"


void Dictionary :: print_tree(Dictionary *p, int level)
{
    Dictionary *print = p;
    if (print)
    {
        std::cout << endl << endl;
        print_tree(print->left,level+1);
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            wcout << L"    ";
        wcout << print->key <<L"  "<< print->Eng_word <<L"   ";
        wcout << print->Rus_word << endl;
        print_tree(print->right,level+1);
    }
}

 Dictionary* Dictionary::add_root(Dictionary *root, wchar_t *buf, bool flag,  bool fl_buf)
{
    root = new Dictionary;
    if (fl_buf)
    {
        root->key = _wtoi(buf);
        wcsncpy(root->Eng_word, buf + l_key, l_Eng_words);
        root->Eng_word[wcslen(root->Eng_word) + 1] = '\0';
        wcsncpy(root->Rus_word, buf + l_key + l_Eng_words, l_Rus_words);
        root->Rus_word[wcslen(root->Rus_word) + 1] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        wcin >> root->key;
        wcin >> root->Eng_word;
        wcin >> root->Rus_word;
    }
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
    return root;
}

 Dictionary * Dictionary::search_and_add_second(Dictionary *root, const wchar_t *buf, bool fl_buf )
 {
     Dictionary *t = root;
     Dictionary *prev;
     Dictionary *pnew = new Dictionary;
     if (fl_buf)
     {
         pnew->key = _wtoi(buf);
         wcsncpy(pnew->Eng_word, buf + l_key, l_Eng_words);
         pnew->Eng_word[wcslen(root->Eng_word) + 1] = '\0';
         wcsncpy(pnew->Rus_word, buf + l_Eng_words, l_Rus_words);
         pnew->Rus_word[wcslen(root->Rus_word) + 1] = '\0';
     }
     else
     {
         wcin >> pnew->key;
         wcin >> pnew->Eng_word;
         wcin >> pnew->Rus_word;
     }
     pnew->left = pnew->right = NULL;
     bool flag = false;
     while (t && !flag)
     {
         prev = t;
         if (wcscmp(pnew->Eng_word,t->Eng_word) == 0)//получается нечто вроде дерева поиска только по алфавиту
             flag = true;
         else if (wcscmp(pnew->Eng_word,t->Eng_word) < 0)
             t = t->left;
         else
             t = t->right;
     }
     if (flag)
         return t;
     if (wcscmp(pnew->Eng_word, prev->Eng_word) < 0)
         prev->left = pnew;
     else
        prev->right = pnew;
     return pnew;
 }
```

Comment: А почему вы в вашем классе `Dictionary` используете ручное управление памятью вместо `std::wstring`? В этом и ваша проблема.

Comment: (А вывод на консоль на русском делается [так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105).)

Comment: @VladD, проблема, как я считаю, не в этом. Я экспериментировал с wcsncpy и в конечном аргументе этой функции добавлял большее количество символов для копирования из одной строки в другую, т.е делал так  wcsncpy(pnew->Eng_word, buf + l_key, l_Eng_words +l_key) и   wcsncpy(pnew->Rus_word, buf + l_key + l_Eng_words, l_buf). Не знаю почему программа выводила (в случае использования одной функции add_root и при количестве одной записи "1    Solt                           Соль" в txt файле) все корректно и русскую Соль и английскую Solt и цифру 1.

Comment: @VladD, не использую string, потому что хочу оставить это на потом в изучении C++, а приведенный выше в моем комментарии способ не сработал в дальнейшем при использовании другого метода search_and_add_second, происходил перехват ошибки с использованием памяти. За дельный совет спасибо!

Comment: Ну, работа с `std::wstring` **гораздо** проще работы с `wchar_t*`-строками, так что я бы порекомендовал оставить сишные строки на потом, а начать с простого.

Comment: @VladD, вы были правы насчет вывода на консоль русских букв. SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); и переход на шрифт lucida console свершили волшебство.

Comment: То есть проблема была только в выводе?

Comment: @VladD, как оказалось да. Отображается все. Правда пришлось везде поменять wchar_t на char и соответствующие поддерживающие этот тип функции (например wcsncpy на strncpy, wcscpy на strcpy и т.д ). Отображались и некоторые "кракозябры", но оказалось я намудрил с присвоением к последнему элементу в некоторых char-овских массивах нулевого символа, вот и все.

Comment: В-первом случае моя ошибка возможно состояла и в том, что я использовал в программе и cout и wcout.

Comment: Окей, тогда вопрос можно закрывать как дубликат?

Comment: @VladD, скорее да.

Comment: Готово, закрыл.