# Сложение string + string[i]

Tags: c++, c

Как объявить "char password_value[1000] = "";" от "password_length"?

Как сложить "password_value += password_chars[j];" ?

Так выдает ошибку, а если я использую "strcat(password_value += password_chars[j]);", то вместо 2 символов получаю почему-то больше.

```
if(!error)
    {
            char s_russian[33] =
            {
                    "àáâãäå¸æçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ"
            };
            char s_latin[27] =
            {
                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            };
            char S_RUSSIAN[33] =
            {
                    "ÀÁÂÃÄÅ¨ÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞß"
            };
            char S_LATIN[27] =
            {
                    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            };
            char s_num[11] =
            {
                    "0123456789"
            };
            char s_esc[27] =
            {
                    "`~@#¹$;%^:&?*()-_=+|[{]}<>"
            };


            char password_chars[153] = "";


            if(CheckBox1->Checked == true && CheckBox3->Checked == true)
            {
                   strcat(password_chars, s_russian);
            }
            if(CheckBox2->Checked == true && CheckBox3->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, s_latin);
            }
            if(CheckBox1->Checked == true && CheckBox4->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, S_RUSSIAN);
            }
            if(CheckBox2->Checked == true && CheckBox4->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, S_LATIN);
            }
            if(CheckBox5->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, s_num);
            }
            if(CheckBox6->Checked == true)
            {
                    strcat(password_chars, s_esc);
            }


            int i = 1;
            int password_length = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);


            int j = 0;
            int password_chars_length = strlen(password_chars);


            char password_value[1000] = "";


            for(i = 1; i <= password_length; i++)
            {
                    j = rand() % password_chars_length + 0;
                    password_value += password_chars[j];

            }


            Edit2->Text =  password_value;
    }
```

Изменил вот так, теперь выводит кракозябры и ругается на память на delete спустя нескольких вызовов.

```
            char * password_value = new char[password_length + 1];


            for(i = 1; i <= password_length; i++)
            {
                     j = rand() % password_chars_length;
                     password_value += password_chars[j];

            }


            password_value[password_length] = 0;


            Edit2->Text =  password_value;


            delete[] password_value;
```

Выбираю цифры, длина 22, рандом выводит "abOrder" и прочую чушь

Comment: Ответ на вопрос скорее всего это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/216418

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
for(i = 0; i < password_length; i++)
{
    j = rand() % password_chars_length;
    password_value[i] = password_chars[j];
}
password_value[password_length] = 0;
```

Сделать `password_value` длиной `password_length` можно только динамически

```
password_value = new char[password_length+1];
```

но потом надо не забыть освободить память... или просто использовать `string password_value`. Тогда

```
for(i = 0; i < password_length; i++)
{
    j = rand() % password_chars_length;
    password_value += password_chars[j];
}
```

Comment: password_value[password_length] = 0; а это что?

Comment: может password_value[password_length + 1] = 0;

Comment: В C/C++ индексация начинается с нуля. Так что именно 
`password_value[password_length] = 0` - это будет `password_length+1`-ый символ.

Comment: А так rand идёт от 0?

Comment: [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(124): E2451 Undefined symbol 'password_value' при объявлении динамически

Comment: `rand()` возвращает значение от 0 до `RAND_MAX` включительно. `RAND_MAX` теоретически зависит от компилятора.

Comment: А вы его объявили как `char*`? Или вы намеки считаете готовым кодом, к которому надо приложить только руки, но не голову? :)

Comment: char * password_value = new char[password_length + 1]; Так?)

Comment: Да, так. только не забудьте потом освободить память, когда станет не нужна, как `delete[] password_value;`

Comment: Когда вызываю по клику на кнопку, ругается на память и в строке delete [] password_value;. Более того выводит кракозябры и через раз, то пусто то выводит. Код прикреплю в конец поста

Comment: Выбираю цифры, длина 22, выводит "abOrder"

Comment: Где то ошибка в памяти, что оно достаёт чуть ли не борландские настрйоки мне в edit (fontChars) и после нескольких вызовов ругался на borlandmm.dll

Comment: А `Edit2->Text` у вас какого типа?

Comment: Кракозябры - скорее проблема в кодировке. В Вашей системе я не знаю, как именно работает `Edit2->Text =  password_value;`, может, он просто указатель сохраняет... Убедитесь в работоспособности **того, что предложил я**, здесь: http://ideone.com/cIxOpF