# Не удается вывести текст из файла в кодировке UTF8, содержащий кириллицу на консоль

Tags: c++, файлы, кодировка, utf-8, консоль

Не получается прочитать текст, включающий в себя кириллицу и вывести на консоль  из файла, который имеет кодировку UTF8. Имеется следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("rus_rus.866"));
    std::wcin.imbue(std::locale("rus_rus.866"));

    std::wfstream fout;

    fout.open(L"cd.txt", std::ios::in);

    if (fout.is_open())
    {
        fout.imbue(std::locale("rus_rus.1251"));

        wchar_t ch;
        std::wstring inputT;
        while (fout.get(ch))
            inputT += ch;
        std::wcout << inputT;
        std::wcout << std::endl;

        fout.close();
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Причем если читаемый файл имеет кодировку ANSI, весь текст включая русские буквы отображается корректно, но если файл в кодировке UTF8, то отображается что то вообще не то. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: У нас где-то был большой ответ, посвящённый выводу кириллицы на консоль. Вы его видели?

Comment: Вот он: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299 (но это для Visual Studio/Windows). Какая у вас платформа/компилятор? Это важно.

Comment: @VladD платформа Visual Studio/Windows. Прочитал статью использую _setmode при вводе строк с клавиатуры все отображается, но если считываю текст из файла у которого кодировка UTF-8,  вместо кириллицы продолжает отображаться непонятные символы, английские слова при этом отображаются корректно

Comment: Тогда проблема при чтении, а не при выводе, судя по всему.

Comment: Ну да, вы пишете `fout.imbue(std::locale("rus_rus.1251"));`, а файл у вас в utf-8.

Comment: @VladD Все  надо было прописать     std::locale utf8_to_utf16(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>);
   fout.imbue(utf8_to_utf16);   Правда не особо понял как это работает но буду разбираться. Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Отлично, тогда оформлю в виде ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема делится на две части: как вывести текст и как прочитать его.

Для вывода имеет смысл воспользоваться рекомендацией [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105) (`_setmode(_fileno(...), _O_U16TEXT);` и использование `std::wstring`).

Это означает, что нам нужно прочитать из файла строки из utf-8 в формат `wstring`. Это делается [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607146/276994):

```
fout.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
```

(и должно работать вне зависимости от ширины `wchar_t`). Вы используете `std::locale("rus_rus.1251")`, это не должно работать.