# Улучшение алгоритма кода

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Написал программу обработки и вывода слов, с добавлением к ней нежелательных, при вводе которых она бы писала "BEEP".

```
{
  vector<string> disliked = {"Broccoli", "Peperoni"}; //Вектор нежелательных слов
  string word;

  cout << "Enter the word\n";


  while (cin >> word)
  {
      if (word == disliked[0, 1]) //Проверка слова на наличие в векторе
      cout << "BEEEP!!" << endl;

      else
      cout << "You entered " << word << endl;
  }

keep_window_open();

return 0;

}
```

Это то, что у меня получилось. Но, как видите, при увеличении вектора, мне придется дописывать еще цифры в `if (word == disliked[0, 1])`. А как бы сделать так, чтобы программа автоматически при добавлении слов в вектор, добавляла бы их и в проверку?

Comment: Ну и за одно вопрос, возможно ли каким-то способом заставить программу выводить кириллицу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знаете, что *на самом деле* вы написали тут?

```
if (word == disliked[0, 1])
```

Проверку на равенство с `disliked[1]`. Потому что запятая - это оператор для последовательного выполнения инструкций; в качестве результата берется последнее значение. У вас в квадратных скобках получилось две инструкции - `0` (который игнорируется, и о котором должен был выдать предупреждение компилятор) и `1`, который и становится результатом...

А вот что вы хотели написать :) -

можно более кратко, с использованием `std::find` из `<algorithm>`:

```
while (cout << "Enter the word: ", cin >> word)
{
    // Проверка, есть ли слово word в векторе
    if (find(disliked.begin(), disliked.end(),word) != disliked.end())
        cout << "BEEEP!!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "You entered " << word << endl;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что тут - `while (cout << "Enter the word: ", cin >> word)` - я использовал упомянутый оператор-запятую, чтоб просить ввести слово для каждого слова, а не один раз для всех вводимых слов.

Можно подробнее, чтоб вам было понятнее - просто проходим по элементам с помощью цикла:

```
while (cout << "Enter the word: ", cin >> word)
{
    bool found = false;                          // Флаг, что слово найдено
    for(size_t i = 0; i < disliked.size(); ++i)  // Проход по всем словам
        if (word == disliked[i])                 // Если найдено
        {
            found = true;                        // выставляем флаг и
            break;                               // покидаем цикл (дальше искать не смысла)
        }
    if (found)                                   // Было найдено
        cout << "BEEEP!!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "You entered " << word << endl;
}
```

О русских буквах - смотрите ответы на этот вопрос: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Comment: А я на первый взгляд решил, что это `0,1` вообще не скомпилируется. Все-таки эту запятую редко встретишь.

Comment: @Mikhailo Иногда она оказывается очень полезной. Но, конечно, помнить только то, чем пользуешься, - обычное свойство человека :)

Answer (score 0):

К тому что уже написал @Harry добавлю что для таких целей лучше использовать [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) или [`std::unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/). Поиск в `std::vector` выполняется за линейное время([O(n)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0#.D0.9B.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B9.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8F)), `std::set` - логарифмическое([О(log(n))](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0#.D0.9B.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8F)), `std::unordered_set` - амортизированное константное([O(1)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.8F.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8F)).

```
#include <set>

//...

std::set<std::string> disliked = {"Broccoli", "Peperoni"};

//...

if(disliked.count(word)){        // Если найдено

    //...
}
```