# Не могу убрать крякозябры в кодировке Sublime Text

Tags: c, кодировка, sublime-text, mingw, компилятор

Всем привет
Не могу никак избавиться от плохой кодировки в компиляторе MinGW для Windows.
Язык написания кода Си, на выходе получается какая-то дичь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К сожалению метод с Fallback_encoding не помогло. Компилятор и дальше начинает творить что хочет. Путь к проекту Кириллицу не содержит.

**Сам исходный код проекта**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()

{

    char card_name[3];

    puts("Введите название карты: ");

    scanf("%2s", card_name);

    int val = 0;

    if (card_name[0] == 'K') {
        val = 10;
    }

        else if (card_name[0] == 'Q') {
            val = 10;
        }

        else if (card_name[0] == 'J') {
            val = 10;
        }

        else {
            atoi(card_name);
        }

    printf("Ценность карты: %i\r\n:", val);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: При чём тут редактор? У вас же вывод в консоли кривой, а не он.

Comment: А в чем может быть проблема? Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, раньше кириллица нормально компилировалась. Пока ничего не помогло.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в исходниках у вас одна кодировка, а в консоли - другая. [Подробней](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299).

Comment: И http://apikabu.ru/img_n/2012-09_2/m38.png

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался!
Спасибо большое PinkTux за правильную наводку.

1) Заходим в сmd и правая кнопка мыши -> свойства -> Шрифты -> Lucida Console

2) Потом сохраняем и пишем в консоль `сhcp`
Отображается `текущая кодовая страница`, она у меня оказалась `886` (формат DOC)

3) После этого пишем в консоль `сhcp 65001`и радуемся жизни!

Код запустился нормально, кириллица работает исправно.