# Проблема чтения русских букв компилятором

Tags: c++

Допустим. дано предложение: "Я хочу выучить С++". Нужна найти количество вхождений буквы "о" в предложение. Как это сделать, если нижеприведенный код может подсчитывать только латинские буквы?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");

    string s;

    getline(cin, s);

    int col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'О' || s[i] == 'о')
            col++;
    }

    cout << col;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Написать вместо латинских русские?... с учетом кодировки, конечно.

Comment: @Harry, в том-то и дело, что он не считывает русские буквы. Точнее считывает в консоли, но не ведет из подсчет. Я пробовал записывать у ветвление латинские буквы в условие - все робит. А вот с русскими беда

Comment: учитывая, что автор вопроса пишет "setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");" - похоже он работает под виндой. А о том, что там мессиво из трех кодировок - он не знает. Поэтому, есть несколько вариантов - от того, что бы в редакторе выставить кодировку cp866 или в консоли выставить cp1251/utf (и в редакторе также). Также можно переопределить операторы ввода-вывода и работать....

Comment: @KoVadim, можете пояснить, как это сделать чуть подробнее? Первый раз слышу просто про "месиво из 3 кодировок"

Comment: @KoVadim Лично я просто плюнул и когда дело касается консоли, все пишу в 866 кодировке, не мучаясь :)

Comment: внутри виндовс живет три кодировки - cp866, стараю досовская, которая осталась по наследству для совместимости, cp1251, которая осталась от 95-98 винды и вылазит местами и utf-16, которая внутри ядра.  Но иногда `chcp 65001` в консоли делает ее более сговорчивой.

Comment: @Harry, а как это сделать, что нужно прописать в коде, чтобы у меня заработало? Первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда символы просто не читаются

Comment: Переходите на линукс. там, если только не постараться, этой проблемы нет.

Comment: @KoVadim, а как быть в винде? что нужно прописать, чтобы код начал работать?

Comment: Нужно правильно задать кодировку.

Comment: http://cppstudio.com/post/435/

Comment: @KoVadim, ничего не изменилось. Там сказано только о том, как русские буквы выводить. Но в моем случае их не надо выводить, а надо подсчитывать

Comment: Читайте до конца.

Comment: может помочь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/216418

Comment: там `о` в условии на каком языке? сам файл-код в какой кодировке?