# TCHAR символы не отображаются корректно

Tags: c, visual-studio, кодировка, консоль, unicode

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. У меня есть простой код, в качестве аргумента командной строки подаю "Привет".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <locale.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR buf[100];

    _fgetts(buf, 100, stdin);

    _tprintf(TEXT("\nargv[1] %s\n"), argv[1]);
    _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), buf);
}
```

В консоль я пишу "Мир" и вижу следующий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавить setlocale(LC_ALL, ""), то результат уже вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне корректно вывести обе строки? _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT) тоже пробовал. Использую VS 2015, в насторйкай стоит Use unicode characters.

Comment: А посмотрите, определено ли у вас `UNICODE` и `_UNICODE` (это две разные штуки).

Comment: `_setmode` должно работать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105. Попробуйте рецепт из того ответа.

Comment: А файл вы сохранили как unicode?

Comment: Причём тут файл? Локаль не установлена может быть.

Comment: @0andriy: А вы пробовали на английской системе открыть cpp-файл с кириллическими символами, сохранёнными не как Unicode? Попробуйте.

Comment: Я по коду в упор не вижу каким образом это релевантно к вопросу, извините.

Comment: Автору. Посмотрел ещё раз на вопрос. Короче, две ошибки мне кажется тут. Как вы правильно заметили, нужно выставлять локаль, а вторая (похоже!) в банальном двойном перекодировании. *_fgetts()* по-видимому возвращает C строку, а вы ещё по ней *_tprintf()*'ом.

Comment: @tproger: А вы делали setmode только для stdout или для stdin тоже?

Comment: @VladD  Простите, что отвечаю через столько много времени, я использовал setmode только на stdout. Вы правы, добавил недостающие setmode и все заработаботало, спасибо)

Comment: @tproger: Вот и отлично! Одной загадкой меньше.

Answer (score 1):

TCHAR - это универсальный char. Который, определён как:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
typedef wchar_t TCHAR;
#else
typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
```

Что это значит? Это значит, что всё зависит от настроек проекта.

Посмотрите, что вы выставили, вот тут.

[image: unicode]

Макрос _UNICODE будет включен если вы укажите «Use Unicode Character set» и тогда тип TCHAR будет определен как wchar_t. Когда же вы укажите «Use Multi-byte character set» TCHAR будет определен как char.