# Как в Visual Studio C++ добиться правильного отображения в окне отладчика строк, написанных с использованием кириллицы?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, кириллица

Как в Visual Studio C++ добиться правильного отображения в окне отладчика строк, написанных с использованием кириллицы при хранении в типе char?
Комплект: Windows 7 US English + MS Visual Studio 2017.

Снимок экрана показывает суть проблемы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема не только в строках, которые внутри программы, но и в текстах, загружаемых из файлов. То есть сохранение в UTF-8 здесь не помогает.

Немного о специфике проблемы:

Я знаю, что правильный ответ "использовать UNICODE, _T(), wchar_t и т.д.". Мне этот ответ не подходит, т.к. нужен именно 8-ми битный char по ряду причин:

1. Задача требует обработки больших объёмов текстов и удвоение объёма
   занимаемой памяти сразу приведёт к потере производительности. Как
   минимум за счёт вылета из кэшей.
2. Мне не хочется переписывать везде char на wchar_t, а также все
   другие типы (вида std::string) и вызовы API. Знаю, что это -
   единственно правильный путь и что только так можно работать с
   локализацией, но в данном случае хочется этого избежать.
3. Есть большое количество кода, где используется 8-ми битный char в
   старых приложениях и его тоже порой надо отлаживать – поддержка,
   никуда не деться.

Я разместил чуть больше информации тут: http://tenisheff.ru/programming/questions/vs_cpp_rus_chars.html и буду поддерживать там актуальное состояние вопросов-ответов.

Comment: Ну, хм. То есть да, `wchar_t` — это хорошее, правильное решение. Если с ним никак, посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105), особенно раздел «Менее правильные, но пригодные решения».

Comment: Думаю, что вам таки придётся править системную кодовую страницу. Отладчик VS скорее всего показывает данные, используя эту (системную) кодовую страницу. Не забудьте перегрузиться после изменений.

Comment: VladD,
Спасибо за ответы. К сожеланию, не могу найти возможности написать в личку на сайте, поэтому оставляю продолжение вопроса здесь: как именно надо в данном случае исправлять системную кодовую страницу?

Comment: Личных сообщений на сайте нет, но я часто сижу в [главном чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Замена кодовой страницы описана [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105), ищите текст «_Если компьютер ваш, вы можете поменять кодовую страницу консольных программ на вашей системе_».

Answer (score 2):

Проблема вызывана известной ошибкой в MS Visual Studio:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244619/debugger-watch-window-codepage

Всё, что требуется сделать устновить русский язык в Control Panel/Region and Language/Formats/Format   (вот же догадались откуда брать).

К сожалению, это значится как минорный баг. Поправят, видимо, не скоро. Но по крайней мере, есть решение.

Comment: Ага, я вижу, что вы сами написали уже ответ. Думаю, что ваш метод и метод из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105 равнозначны.

Comment: К сожалению - нет. Я перепробовал все варианты с этой страницы и ни один из них не подошёл. В основном по той причине, что они адресуют проблемы либо Code Page консоли, либо Code Page редактора. А здесь проблема именно в Code Page окон отладчика. 
Если Вы считаете, что я пропустил какой-то из вариантов, описанных на этой странице - скажите, какой именно Вы имеете в виду - я проверю ещё раз и поясню, почему это не работает. К примеру, только что перепроверил вариант с правкой реестра - он относится только к консоли.
Но в любом случае - спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Интересно, да. Окно отладчика использует _системную_ кодовую страницу (которую меняете вы), но я думал, что она совпадает с кодовой страницей _консоли_ (которая меняется в реестре). Судя по всему, это не так.