# Не вызывается деструктор у класса

Tags: c++, locale

Доброго времени суток. Имеется класс, который изменяет кодировку консоли. Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

class edit_locale
{
    int old_cin;
    int old_cout;
public:
   edit_locale(int);
   ~edit_locale();
};

int main()
{
    edit_locale(1251);
    std::cout << "Иван" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}


edit_locale::edit_locale(int cp)
{
   this->old_cin = GetConsoleCP();
   this->old_cout = GetConsoleOutputCP();
   SetConsoleCP(cp);
   SetConsoleOutputCP(cp);
}

edit_locale::~edit_locale()
{
   SetConsoleCP(this->old_cin);
   SetConsoleOutputCP(this->old_cout);
}
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: функция SetConsole срабатывает только в конструкторе, в main - функции изменений не происходит. И деструктор не вызывается. С чем это может быть связано? Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в строчке

```
edit_locale(1251);
```

Вы создаёте временный объект, который тут же, в этой же строчке уничтожается.

Пишите так:

```
edit_locale l(1251);
```

Comment: Кстати, можно и временным обойтись - как по мне, так даже в каком-то смысле красивей :) - см. дополнение в моем ответе.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте создать объект :)

```
int main()
{
    edit_locale el(1251);
    std::cout << "Иван" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Без этого в `main()` создается (и тут же, до вывода строки) уничтожается временный объект.

[Чтоб было понятнее](http://ideone.com/drGSgP) -

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    test()  { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
   ~test()  { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
};

void f()
{
    test();
    std::cout << "in f\n";
}

void g()
{
    test t;
    std::cout << "in g\n";

}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "call f()\n";
    f();
    std::cout << "call g()\n";
    g();
}
```

**Update**

Можно обойтись и временным объектом - если поступить так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

class edit_locale
{
    int old_cin;
    int old_cout;
public:
    template<typename T>
        edit_locale(int,T f);
    ~edit_locale();
};

int main()
{
    edit_locale{1251,[](){

        std::cout << "Иван" << std::endl;

    }};

    return 0;
}


template<typename T>
edit_locale::edit_locale(int cp, T f)
{
    this->old_cin = GetConsoleCP();
    this->old_cout = GetConsoleOutputCP();
    SetConsoleCP(cp);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(cp);
    f();
};

edit_locale::~edit_locale()
{
    SetConsoleCP(this->old_cin);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(this->old_cout);
}
```

Кстати, мне всегда хотелось в C++ иметь возможность для всяких lock'ов и иже с ними писать не

```
{
    lock lk;

    // что-то делаем
}
```

а

```
lock{

    // что-то делаем
}
```

Так, по-моему, выглядит понятнее. С лямбдами имеем определенный суррогат...

Comment: Пожалуйста, никому не рассказывайте, что я создал этот вопрос..да как так-то блин...Как я просмотрел?:D 
Спасибо!

Comment: @Range Договорились :)

Comment: @Range Кстати, гляньте дополнение к ответу...

Comment: @Harry: За такими дополнениями добро пожаловать в C# :) Там для таких целей есть конструкция `using`: `using (TemporaryLocale(1251)) { Console.WriteLine("ляляфафа"); }`.

Comment: @Harry: С новой `edit_locale` проблема будет, если кто-то случайно таки запишет её в переменную: `edit_locale{1251,[](){ ... }} l;`.

Comment: @VladD Ну, да... Но все равно на C# не перейду :)

Comment: @Harry: На C++ наверняка можно сделать тоже какой-нибудь костыль с препроцессором, да.

Comment: @VladD А так? http://ideone.com/h9QNOB

Comment: @Harry: Уже ближе к идеалу :) Ещё макросом автоматически добавлять `[](){`, засунуть в стандартный do/while(0), и будет костыль что надо.

Comment: @Harry смотрел, благодарю. Интересный способ, однако..