# Как в Visual C++ заставить работать isupper и другие подобные функции с кириллицей

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, кириллица

Как заставить правильно работать следующий код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    isupper('П');

    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что в Release он падает, а в Debug выдаёт ASSERT: Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255.

У меня есть несколько вариантов решения, но все не подходят в той или иной степени:

1. Перейти на UNICODE - не могу, т.к. поддерживается проект с большим
   объёмом такого кода.
2. Можно использовать перегруженную функцию isupper, принимающую в качестве второго аргумента locale. Не могу по той же причине - не хочется везде переписывать вызовы.
3. Удивительно, но работает вариант с isupper((unsinged char)'П'). То
   есть всё-таки RTL понимает setlocale и работает с русскими буквами. 
   (Это подтверждается тем, что если убрать setlocale, то компилироваться будет, но результаты isupper будет возвращать неправильные.) Но вот ASSERT этого не понимает и срабатывает вне зависимости от локали, что понятно, но плохо.
4. Схожий с (3) вариант поставить ключ компиляции /J (Make char as unsigned char) не подходит - несовместим с библиотеками, например MFC.
5. Писать свои функции isupper_rus и подставлять их define'ами - плохой способ, как и переписывать RTL.

Вопрос: возможно ли решить проблему без значительнного переписывания кода, предложенного выше? То есть можно ли сделать, чтобы работал именно isupper?

Comment: Я бы предложил в качестве долгосрочного решения перейти не Unicode и широкие строки. А то у вас начнутся проблемы с выводом на консоль тоже. Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105

Comment: Я бы рад, но, как я написал в п.1 - проект большой и кода много. Переписывать его - долго. Плюс он обрабатывает большие объёмы текстовых данных - удвоить эти объёмы - потерять производительность, как минимум из-за вылета из кэшей.

И ещё одна неприятность UNICODE - везде писать wchar_t, вместо привычного char, wstring вместо string - неприятно. Хотя и понятно, что правильно. Странно, что это не сделано на уровне опции компилятора. Вернее, сделано, но как-то не до конца. Впрочем, я понимаю - почему.

Comment: Я понимаю эту проблему, вы описали её пунктом 1. Поэтому и не предлагаю это как ответ, а лишь как намётки на будущее. (Лет 10 назад было, кажется, принято использовать везде `TCHAR`. С ним было бы легче.)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что функция принимает int, но предполагает при этом, что коды символов >0, а символ 'П' меньше нуля! Мы для работы с кириллицей ставили ключ компилятора /J, который делает char по умолчанию беззнаковым (0..255). Когда-то был такой пункт в настройках, сейчас можно просто добавить в командную строку.
Сверхпроблем от этого ключа, вроде, нет.

Кстати, вместо wchar_t (который все равно не охватывает весь Юникод!) можно использовать utf-8. При этом передача текста между модулями не меняется совсем, но языковая обработка меняется сильно.