# C++.Символы, сравнение символов

Tags: c++

Суть программы в том, что для введеного символа надо вывести латинский или русский это символ, также учесть его регистр. Подскажите как сделать это проще.

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
  char i;
  cin >>i;
  char e1 = 'A';
  char e2 = 'Z';
  char e3 = 'a';
  char e4 = 'z';
  char ru1 = 'А';
  char ru2 = 'Я';
  char ru3 = 'а';
  char ru4 = 'я';
  if ((i>=e1)&&(i<=e2)){cout <<"ENG";}
  if ((i>=e3)&&(i<=e4)){cout <<"eng";}
  if ((i>=ru1)&&(i<=ru2)){cout <<"RU";}
  if ((i>=ru3)&&(i<=ru4)){cout <<"ru ";}
  else{cout <<"error";}

  return a.exec();
```

Comment: Вы хотите еще проще чем у вас?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Эта функция проверяет, является ли символ символом в верхнем регистре:

```
isupper(character)
```

Эта функция проверяет, является ли символ символом в нижнем регистре:

```
islower(character)
```

Можете использовать их и сократить свои условные выражения

```
if ((i>=ru1)&&(i<=ru2)){cout <<"RU";}
if ((i>=ru3)&&(i<=ru4)){cout <<"ru ";}
```

Проверьте только, как эти функции реагируют на русский алфавит. А реагируют они плохо. Вот в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/710931/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-visual-c-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-isupper-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86) обсуждалась эта проблема. Обратите внимание, в ответе говорится, что в настройках студии можно поставить ключ, делающий `char` беззнаковым, а можно использовать `wchar_t`. Также можете посмотреть в сторону `std::locale` из `<locale>`.

Comment: не забывайте о букве Ё. Она не входит в указанный диапазон.