# Как вывести ровную таблицу в консоли с++?

Tags: c++

Помогите с лабой пожалуйста: учим С,  и эта прога должна выводить ровную табличку в консоли, но у меня вместо русских символов оркские и сама таблица кривая (может из-за оркских символов).
Вот код, запускаю через Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "locale.h" 

int main()
{
    char computer1[10], computer2[10], computer3[10];
    char type1, type2, type3, ram1, ram2, ram3;

    float frq1, frq2, frq3;
    /* Введение фактических данных*/
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    printf("1. Введите: процессор, Частоту, RAM, тип >");
    scanf("%s %f %c %c",computer1, &frq1, &ram1, &type1);
    printf("2. Введите: процессор, Частоту, RAM, тип >");
    scanf("%s %f %c %c",computer2, &frq2, &ram2, &type2);
    printf("3. Введите: процессор, Частоту, RAM, тип >");
    scanf("%s %f %c %c",computer3, &frq3, &ram3, &type3);
    /* Вывод таблицы */
    /* вывод заголовков */
    printf("|---------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|Характеристики ПЭВМ                          |\n");
    printf("|---------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("| Процессор   | Частота (Mgz) | RAM(Mb)   |Тип|\n");
    printf("|-------------|---------------|-----------|---|\n");
    /* вывод строк фактических данных */
    printf("| %10s | %f| %-3d | %c|\n", computer1, frq1, ram1, type1);
    printf("| %10s | %f| %-3d | %c|\n", computer2, frq2, ram2, type2);
    printf("| %10s | %f| %-3d | %c|\n", computer3, frq3, ram3, type3);
    /* вывод примечаний */
    printf("|---------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("| Тип: C-CISC-процессор, R-RISC-процессор     |\n");
    printf("|---------------------------------------------|\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема в стандартном терминале Windows - он не умеет в нормальные кодировки. Более-менее приличное решение есть [тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/435/) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8) (я не проверял работоспособность, но выглядит правдоподобно). Другой вариант - использовать powershell, там можно задавать кодировки на входной и выходной потоки, но это требует чуть ли не прав администратора. Этот вариант я пробовал - работает, но подробностей не помню.

Comment: P.S. Вообще, для выполнения лаб неплохим вариантом является поставить какой-нибудь Linux на виртуалку, на него поставить современную версию gcc и/или clang и QtCreator. По своему опыту могу сказать, что если бы я сделал так с самого начала обучения, сэкономил бы много нервных клеток.

Comment: А еще лучше забыть о винде раз и навсегда)