# Как напечатать символ дельта?

Tags: c++

Нашёл в сети-интернет  `std::cout << "\u0394V" << '\n';` но у меня выводит символ вопроса

Comment: Уточните, в какой среде вы это делаете.

Comment: В windows 10. Компилятор visual studio

Comment: потому что печатаете в терминале, который по умолчанию настроен на кодировку  866. Переключите на юникод (например, перейдя на линукс:) ) и будет счастье.

Comment: линукс мне не подходит, наверное есть другое решение.

Comment: Здесь целый ряд факторов, начиная с кодировки файла исходного кода, кодовой страницы консоли, шрифта консоли и, самое сложное - stream-ы в visual studio не гарантируют передачу в консоль вашего символа за один вызов api.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan а зачем гарантировать за один вызов?

Comment: @alexolut Например если код символа двухбайтовый, для utf-8 может быть напечатано два символа.

Comment: VladimirGamalyan так если консоль правильно настроена, она не должна печатать полусимволы

Answer (score 1):

Перейдите на широкие строки, как описано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105) в разделе «Правильное, но сложное решение».

После этого ваша программа будет иметь вид

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin),  _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"Δδ" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Нет, просто скопировать текст примера недостаточно, нужно ещё сделать то, что описано в ответе по ссылке выше.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Но всё равно как-то сложновато

Comment: @Ilya: Ну, было бы просто, мы бы были не нужны :) // Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
#include "iostream"
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);             // Переключение консоли на кодировку 65001 (утф-8) 
    std::cout << u8"\u0394" << std::endl;  // Печать символа 0394 (дельта)

    return 0;
}
```

К сожалению непортабельно, но для студии и Win как раз.

u8 - строковый литерал, сообщающий, что строку следует интерпретировать как утф-8 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx)

Comment: если написать `u8"\u0394"` то выводить ковычки, а если  `"\u0394"` то знак вопроса