# вывод в консоли на русском конфликт

Tags: c++, visual-c++, консоль

пробую вывести в VC++ 2017 в консоль русские буквы. Setlocale и chcp не помогли, помогло только 
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
wcout << L"Сколько автомобилей поместить в каталог?";

Но теперь когда пытаюсь вывести string оно кидает какой-то exception после вывода "Вот ваша коллекция: ". В чём проблема? Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(void)
{
    using namespace std;
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    struct car {
        string name;
        int year;
    };
    int qnt;
    wcout << L"Сколько автомобилей поместить в каталог?";
    cin >> qnt;
    car *cars = new car[qnt];
    for (int i = 0; i < qnt; i++)
    {
        wcout << L"Автомобиль #" << i + 1 << endl;
        cin.get();
        wcout << L"Введите производителя:";
        getline(cin, cars[i].name);
        wcout << L"Укажите год выпуска:";
        cin >> cars[i].year;
    }
    wcout << L"Вот ваша коллекция: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < qnt; i++) {
        cout << cars[i].name << " ";
        cout << cars[i].year;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тут вылетает на cout year. закомментируйте и посмотрите, будет ли работать.

Comment: Поставьте точку останова, после нее пошаговый прогон, так увидите причину.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka оказывается с wcout надо использовать wstring. мне было был интересно, как есть ли другие способы переключения на UTF16 который поддерживает много других символом, кроме _setmode? с которым можно как я понял использовать wcout.

Comment: Мне удалось добиться корректной работы программы. Написала 2 строчки. Добавлю в ответ

Comment: Везде пишите wcout, wcin. Год можно и через cin cout, но лучше для единообразия так.

Comment: В вопросе "Setlocale и chcp не помогли", ведь нужен и ввод, и вывод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объявите `

```
wstring name
```

Для хранения unicode обычный не годится. И во время ввода также

```
getline(wcin, cars[i].name);
```

Вместо _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

```
 wcout.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
    wcin.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
```

Comment: Совет насчёт кодировки 866 не самый хороший: в однобайтной кодировке неизбежно пропадут некоторые символы.

Comment: Консоль поддерживает юникод?

Comment: Разумеется, поддерживает.

Comment: Тогда дайте ответ, более правильный. Так как на практике срабатывает только этот код.

Comment: У нас уже давно есть канонический ответ по этой теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105

Comment: А проблема автора, как он и написал, в использовании `std::string` вместо `std::wstring`.

Comment: Это написала вначале я.

Comment: Но все равно, введенные русские символы не отображались правильно.

Comment: Посмотрите в канонический ответ, то, что там расписано, работает везде. Но нужно не только скопировать код оттуда, а и прочитать весь текст первого раздела.