# "Русский" unicode в консоли

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Имею стандартную проблему. Код:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"абвгдейка" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Настройки проекта: использовать набор символов unicode. Шрифт в консоли тоже менял. Перепробовал уйму вариантов, так ничего и не подошло. Использую VS17. ранее стояла 15, на которой код, предложенный выше, прекрасно работал.
P.S.: да, тема стара, как мир, да, гуглил очень много, и ни один способ не заработал. 
P.S.S.: меня интересует русская локализация с юникодом *обязательно.*

Comment: Файл исходного кода сохранен в юникоде?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov проверял. Да, в юникоде.

Comment: Пробовали с wcout?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka дак мой пример кода именно с широким потоком)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730510/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82/730514#730514

Comment: Вот недавно отвечала,  wcout.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
    wcin.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866")); прекрасно работает.

Comment: @Ах вот Вы о чём. Увы, пробовал, мимо. Сейчас вписал вновь - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [C++ вывод “галочки” на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571428/23044)

Comment: Поменяйте шрифт консоли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим способом: у файла, почему-то, не установилась кодировка Unicode. WordPad исправил эту проблему, и все заработало.