# Перевод букв русского алфавита в верхний регистр

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Enter the string, which is smaller than 80 symbols: "<<endl;
    char string[81];
    gets_s(string);
    for (int i = 0; string[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] > 192 && string[i] < 255) {
            string[i] = toupper(string[i]);
        }
    }
    cout << string << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Задача - перевод букв русского алфавита в верхний регистр. Однако при вводе любой строки, к примеру "привет", на выходе получаю `яЁштхЄ`. В чём проблема?

Comment: А если #include <locale.h> ?

Comment: nick_gabpe, все равно нет

Comment: А какая у вас кодировкам консоли? Выведите строку до преобразования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых цикл ничего не делает.
В VC++ по умолчанию `char` имеет максимальное значение 127, и условие `string[i] > 192` всегда ложно.

Используйте unsigned char, например

```
for (int i = 0; string[i]!='\0'; i++) {
    unsigned char c = string[i];
    if (c > 192 && c < 255) {
        string[i] = toupper(c);
    }
}
```

(Также в `toupper` нельзя передавать отрицательные значения.)

---

А во-вторых `яЁштхЄ` это вывод исходной строки `привет`.
Добавьте `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);`.
Подробнее тут - [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется надо вот так сделать

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
  clrscr();
  char str[20];
  int i;
  cout<<"Введи строку: ";
  cin>>str;
  for(i=0;i<=strlen(str);i++)
  {
        if(str[i]>=192 && str[i]<=223)
        {
        str[i]=str[i]+32;
        }
  }
  cout<<"\n Строка с верхним регистром = "<<str;
  getch();
}
```

Соответсвенно в твоем коде это должно ВРОДЕ так выглядеть:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Enter the string, which is smaller than 80 symbols: "<<endl;
    char string[81];
    gets_s(string);
    for (int i = 0; string[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] > 192 && string[i] < 223) {
            string[i] = string[i]+32;
        }
    }
    cout << string << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```