# Оператор if игнорирует символы

Tags: c, операторы

Нужно считать с клавиатуры строку и вывести соответствующую оценку. На деле оно постоянно выводит что такой оценки нет

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    char x[20];
    gets_s(x);

    if (x=="неудовлетворительно") puts("2");
    if (x=="удовлетворительно")  puts("3");
    if (x=="хорошо")  puts("4");
    if (x=="отлично")  puts("5");
    else puts("такой оценки нет");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: метку языка добавьте.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что в C строки так не сравниваются.

В C нету отдельного типа данных для строк со своей операцией сравнения. В C под строкой подразумевается указатель типа `char*`, указывающий на первый символ. Соответственно при сравнении происходит сравнение указателей — на `x` и на расположенный где-то в памяти литерал `"неудовлетворительно"`. А указатели будут разными, даже если и содержимое строк одинаковое.

Для сравнения строк используйте `strcmp`, он сравнивает именно строки.

Да, и чтобы не было проблем с кириллицей, имеет смысл заглянуть [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105) (и перейти на `wchar_t`).

Comment: Пора вводить тег или шаблон `C==` :)

Comment: @PinkTux: Думаю, имеет смысл кому-нибудь собрать канонический ответ на тему сравнения (и может даже обработки) строк в C. А то буфер фиксированного размера делает мне грустно.

Comment: wchar_t не удовлетворяет хотелкам современного общества, UTF-8 лучше.

Comment: @0andriy: И чем же оно не удовлетворяет? Я что-то никаких рациональных обоснований не видел. (Нет, манифест utf8everywhere за рациональное обоснование не катит.)

Comment: Речь не про манифест, конечно. wchar_t устаревший тип, который вмещает в себя только нулевую страничку юникода. Переносимость его так же плохая.

Comment: @0andriy: Ээээ, а чем он более устаревший по сравнению с `char`? Если вам не нравится `wchar_t`, чем `char` лучше? Не говоря уже о том, что (1) консоль Windows поддерживает UTF-16, но не UTF-8. (2) Наивное использование UTF-16 как UCS-2 ломает только emoji, в то время как наивное использование UTF-8 как однобайтной кодировки ломает все нелатинские символы.