# Какой итератор использовать для копирования в поток wcout?

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы

Пытался так:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> foo;
std::copy(foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring>(std::wcout, L"\n"));
```

Не работает. Знаю, что что-то упускаю, но никак не соображу где.

Comment: А вектор чего? Просто вектор не бывает.

Comment: Небось у вас вектор узких строк?

Comment: vector<std::wstring>, как ни странно компилятору пофиг на тип строк вектора в данном случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> foo{ L"first", L"second" };
std::copy(foo.begin(), foo.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(std::wcout, L"\n"));
```

Если у вас строки с кириллицей, возможно, вам нужно дополнительно воспользоваться советом [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105). Для Visual Studio код будет при этом выглядеть так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::vector<std::wstring> foo{ L"первая", L"вторая" };
    std::copy(foo.begin(), foo.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(std::wcout, L"\n"));
    return 0;
}
```