# Иероглифы при выводе русского текста на Си

Tags: c

Я только начал изучение языка С,и мне понадобилось сделать программу на русском (чтобы можно было выводить фразы на русском и принимать их).
Как это сделать?
Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("%s", "Привет");
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит непонятные иероглифы.

Comment: 1. Проблема может быть с шрифтом в консоли. ПКМ на иконке консоли(лев. верхний угол окна консоли) - defaults - fonts - в списке выбираете "lucida console". 2. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` внутри `main()` перед `printf();`

Comment: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Comment: @rOtK9,пишет: LC_ALL undeclared (first use in this function).

Comment: @wololo,данную статью я читал,но мне ни один метод не помог.

Comment: #include <locale.h> попробуйте

Comment: @rOtK9,программа запустилась,но иероглифы остались.

Comment: Прям таки ни один не помог? Добавьте в вопрос название компилятора / операционной системы.

Comment: `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);` перед `printf();` если у Вас винда попробуйте

Comment: Чтоб поменьше мучиться - работать в 866 кодировке (если это Windows) :)

Comment: @wololo,хорошо.Операционка windows 10,компилю через codelite.

Comment: А исходник в какой кодировке?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Я когда-то делал программы на руском, но это было не очень удобно. Вот пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c.\n", 143, 224, 168, 162, 165, 226);
    return 0;
}
```

Дело в том что для ASCII кодировки стандартом определены только 127 символов, остальные являются расширением.

Можно написать собственную функцию для преобразования символов.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char *cyrillic(unsigned char *string);

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *hello = cyrillic("Привет мир.");
    printf("%s\n", hello);
    return 0;
}

/***********************************************************************
    Функция:    cyrillic()
    Назначение: преобразует входную строку из иероглифов в строку с
                русскими символами.
***********************************************************************/
unsigned char *cyrillic(unsigned char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    int n = strlen(str);

    unsigned char *string = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * n);

    // Перебираем символы пока не встретим символ конца строки.
    while(str[i] != '\0') {
        string[i] = str[i];
        if((string[i] >= 192) && (string[i] <= 239)) {
            // Преобразуем символы А ... п
            string[i] -= 64;
        } else if(string[i] >= 240 && string[i] <= 255) {
            // Преобразуем символы р ... я
            string[i] -= 16;
        } else if(string[i] == 168) {
            // Преобразуем Ё
            string[i] = 240;
        } else if(string[i] == 184) {
            // Преобразуем ё
            string[i] = 241;
        }
        i++;
    } 
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не мучайся, а просто скачай себе Notepad++, где выбери кодировку ANSI во вкладке "кодировки", тогда, например следующий код будет работать как надо (проверено через компилятор gcc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main () 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian_Russia.1251");
    printf("Привет, чёртов мир");
    return 0;
}
```