# Ввод и вывод кириллических строк в языке С

Tags: c, строки, кириллица

Не могу вывести строки el1, el2, el3 в консоль! Вместо русских букв - крокозябры. Что только не пробывал - 0 эффекта.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>



int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
 char el1[1024], el2[1024], el3[1024];
 char g1, g2, g3;
 short zar1, zar2, zar3;
 float mass1, mass2, mass3;
 printf("1. Введите: частицу, группу, заряд, массу покоя >");
 scanf("%s %c %hd %f",&el1, &g1, &zar1, &mass1);
 printf("2. Введите: частицу, группу, заряд, массу покоя >");
 scanf("%s %c %hd %f",&el2, &g2, &zar2, &mass2);
 printf("3. Введите: частицу, группу, заряд, массу покоя >");
 scanf("%s %c %hd %f",&el3, &g3, &zar3, &mass3);
 printf("----------------------------------------------\n");
 printf("|Элементарные частицы                        |\n");
 printf("|--------------------------------------------|\n");
 printf("| Частица  |Группа |   Заряд   |Масса покоя  |\n");
 printf("|          |       |           |             |\n");
 printf("|----------|-------|-----------|-------------|\n");
 printf("| %8s | %5c | %9hd | %11.3f |\n", el1, g1, zar1, mass1);
 printf("| %8s | %5c | %9hd | %11.3f |\n", el2, g2, zar2, mass2);
 printf("| %8s | %5c | %9hd | %11.3f |\n", el3, g3, zar3, mass3);
 printf("|--------------------------------------------|\n");
 printf("|Группы частиц: Г - гипероны, Н - нуклоны,   |\n");
 printf("|               М - мезоны, Л - лептоны      |\n");
 printf("----------------------------------------------\n");
 printf("Нажмите Enter, чтобы завершить программу");
 getchar();
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8).

Comment: **Не могу вывести строки el1, el2, el3 в консоль!** - Что это значит ? Во первых - какая операционка? Судя по "setlocale" - виндовоз? Ну там кирилизация выполняется по разному в разных эмуляторах терминала. Попробуйте запустить Ваш EXE-шник из под FAR, CMD, что там ещё есть - не помню. А! НАдо ещё попробовать из под VS! А проще всего - соберите Вашу программу под люнихом - никаких проблем не будет.