# Расшифровка в "C++" с помощью массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, шифрование

Как осуществить расшифровку текста с данным ключом с помощью массивов? (В "C++" 2-ой месяц)

Подумываю над тем чтобы создать два массива: один шифр, другой ключ. И заменить первый вторым. Но вот беда, не могу взять и заменить одну кириллицу другой.
+ Вообще не читает кириллицу и в командной строке отображаются иероглифы.

Comment: Вообще совсем ничего не понятно. Хотя бы какой шифр - прямая подстановка, замена одного алфавита другим?

Comment: Расшифровать текст: "Руинцирекевфекеестфаитапсьмиуслпрым. МфхфтмфОфнди". Открытый текст: "афгоепрузв". Символы зашифрованного текста: "фгоепрузва".

Comment: Ключ, алгоритм шифрования - известны?

Comment: *Принцип око зa око остaвит весь мир слепым. Мaхaтма Гaнди* - этого достаточно? :)

Comment: @gdb Да у него там проблема в кириллице; расшифровывать там нечего...

Comment: Смотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8/459299#459299

Comment: @Harry "Как осуществить расшифровку текста с данным ключом с помощью массивов?" это был основной вопрос а кириллица уже второстепенное.

Comment: Ну сейчас набросаю :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот ваша расшифровка:

```
char text[] = "руинцирекевфекеестфаитапсьмиуслпрым. мфхфтмфофнди";
char src[]  = "афгоепрузв";
char dst[]  = "фгоепрузва";

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(char * c = text; *c; ++c)
    {
        char * s = strchr(dst,*c);
        if (s) *c = src[s-dst];
        cout << *c;
    }
}
```

Чтоб побыстрее, я

1. писал в 866 кодировке и не заморачивался с русскими буквами.
2. руками преобразовал все символы в нижний регистр.

Принцип до смешного прост - если буква длинного текста есть в зашифрованном тексте ("фгоепрузва") - мы меняем ее на соответствующую букву открытого текста; если нет - оставляем букву как есть...

Comment: Да, такой алгоритм сразу пришел в голову когда впервые встретился с заданием, но не знал как его реализовать. 
char*c/s - это указатели или какие то операторы используемые конкретно для типов char ?

Comment: Указатели на `char`

Answer (score 0):

Если в командной строке иероглифы, то скорее всего кодировка командной строки и файла отличаются. Если вы на линукс, то используйте utf-8