# Как изменить кодировку в консоли Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, консоль, visual-studio-2017, cp1251

[image: Скрин]

Сразу хочу оговориться, что меня не интересуют команды типа `setlocale();` `SetConsoleCP();` и подобные. Если вы хотите предложить вариант как-то связанный с программным исправлением (с добавлением строк кода по исправлению кодировки к каждой программе), пожалуйста, не надо.

Меня интересует, как изменить параметр "Текущая кодовая страница", который сейчас выставлен в свойствах консоли на 866 ?
И желательно изменить один раз, чтобы он выставлялся по умолчанию.

Comment: Кодовая страница консоли не является свойством Visual Studio. Ее можно изменить на уровне ОС установкой определенных ключей реестра: https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8 (но не нужно, так как неизвестно, что от этого сломается)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight В этом вопросе речь о консоли Windows. В консоли windows у меня кодировка 1251. В консоли студии - 866.

Comment: Никакого понятия "консоль студии" не существует. Решение по ссылке в чистом виде к вам действительно не применимо, оно требует дополнительно в свойствах проекта в разделе отладка установить параметры Команда: c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe и Аргументы: /k $(TargetPath)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, теперь моя программа запускается в консоли windows. После завершения программы консоль продолжает работать (ожидает команды), из чего я могу сделать вывод, что для Visual Studio используется нечто другое (вполне вероятно, связанное с консолью windows, т.к. до этого даже значок был другой). Всё таки, можно ли настроить аргументами без команд (чтобы программа открывалась тем, чем открывалась до этого) кодовую страницу этого "нечто другого"?

Comment: У вас Windows 10?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight да

Comment: Можно как-то прописать chcp в автозапуск или подобное если, например, консоль эта запускается из определенной папки? т.е. при запуске консоль проверяет путь запуска программы и, если он совпадает, перед выполнением производит chcp

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight хорошо. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ответы не годятся. Авторы ответов упирают на то, что "отдельной консоли VS не существует". Еще как существует, если консоль рассматривать не как класс, а как экземпляр. Суть вопроса в том, что из Windows и из VS запускаются разные экземпляры консоли с разными настройками, включая кодовую страницу. И задача автора (и моя тоже) в том, чтобы обе консоли запускались с CP 1251.
Изменить CP командной строки Windows с 437 на 1251 можно в реестре путем добавления параметра Autorun "chcp 1251" в раздел Command Processor.
Вопрос в том, как аналогичную операцию проделать с VS?

Comment: chcp — это костыль. вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459154/10105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, кодовая страница для консольных приложений не является настройкой, которую можно изменить через Visual Studio. Дело в том, что не существует никакой "консоли Visual Studio" - при запуске консольного приложения из студии используется самая обычная консоль ОС, та же самая, что и для cmd.exe или любого другого консольного приложения (она может отличаться внешне, в зависимости от настроек, но суть та же). Кодовую страницу для нее можно задать:

- На уровне ОС, установкой [определенных ключей реестра](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)
- В конкретном сеансе командной оболочки, выполнением команды `chcp 1251`. Таким образом, можно изменить действие при запуске приложения (в разделе "Отладка" в свойствах проекта) на `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k chcp 1251 && $(TargetPath)` для достижения требуемого эффекта. Но тогда отладчик будет отлаживать cmd.exe, а не нашу программу :(
- Для конкретного консольного приложения через параметр реестра `HKCU\Console\(путь к приложению)\CodePage` (REG_DWORD).

Используя последний способ и шаблоны проектов, можно автоматизировать установку кодовой страницы для приложений, собираемых в студии.

1. Создадим bat-файл следующего содержания:

   ```
   set MYSTRING=%~1
   reg add "HKCU\Console\%MYSTRING:\=_%" /v CodePage /t REG_DWORD /f /d 1251
   ```

Поместим его, допустим, в папку *c:\scripts\codepage.bat*

2. Создадим проект консольного приложения под шаблон, допустим *Cp1251ConsoleApplication*
3. В свойствах проекта, в разделе **События построения - Событие после построения**, введем в параметр **Командная строка** значение:

   ```
   c:\scripts\codepage.bat "$(TargetPath)"
   ```
4. Нажмем в меню **Файл - Экспорт шаблона** или **Проект - Экспорт шаблона**, зададим параметры шаблона (галка "Автоматически импортировать в Visual Studio" должна быть отмечена), и нажмем **Готово**

Теперь при создании нового проекта в в разделе Visual C++ появится шаблон *Cp1251ConsoleApplication*. Если создавать проект на его основе, при сборке проекта в реестре автоматически будет устанавливаться кодовая страница консоли для этого приложения. Недостаток способа в том, что этот раздел реестра будет замусориваться, если создавать много проектов.

Также, при задействовании команды **Запуск без отладки** способ не сработает: вместо вашего приложения будет запускаться cmd.exe; для него кодовая страница настраивается отдельно - созданием точно такой же ветки в реестре с путем к cmd.exe.

Подробнее о настройках консоли: [Understanding Windows Console Host Settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/06/20/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/)

Comment: Можно ли в третьем способе вместо "путь к приложению" указать папку с проектами, чтобы этот параметр применялся ко всем консольным приложениям внутри папки автоматически?
P. S. Я гораздо хуже понимаю, как работает реестр и обращение к нему проектов (это уточнение на случай, если вопрос слишком тупой)

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko Нет, настройки в реестре можно задать только для конкретного exe-файла.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)