# Символ не отображается корректно

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Написал простой парсер погоды из яндекса, но если температура минусовая, то он выводит знак вопроса. Перепробовал много чего, но пока ничего не помогло. Прошу помочь. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код(Python 3.7)

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def ParseWeatherYandex(city):
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/pogoda/' + city
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    #getting time now, temperature and condition
    day = soup.find('time', 'fact__time').contents
    temperature = soup.find('span', 'temp__value').contents
    weather_type = soup.find('div', 'link__condition day-anchor i-bem').contents

    #parsing feeling temperature
    t = soup.find('dl', 'term term_orient_h fact__feels-like')
    t = ((t.div).span).contents


    #joining lists in one
    feels = list(soup.find('dt', 'term__label').contents) + t


    print(day[0] + '\n' + 'Температура сейчас: '+ (temperature[0]).center(3), end='\n')
    print('Погода: %s' %weather_type[0], end=', ')
    print('%s %s' %(feels[0].lower(), feels[1]))



ParseWeatherYandex(input())

input()
input()
```

Comment: Может, с кодировкой консоли проблема? Если `chcp 65001` написать, лучше не станет?

Comment: Копировал ваш код, заменив `import urllib` на `import requests`, `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')`, всё выдало правильно (подал на вход Tomsk, там сейчас минусовая :)).

Comment: Ну и как вариант в `feels`, наверное, строка лежит - можно проверять, является ли её первый символ цифрой (`feels[0].isdigit()`), если нет - то это какой-то дефис или тире, можно на отображающийся символ заменить, например, на собственно минус

Comment: @Anton я в питоне недавно, подскажите как попробовать кодировку в вашем сообщении

Comment: @HideME - прям в консоль написать, из которой запускаете скрипт (у Вас же windows?) - `chcp 65001` - это должно на utf-8 сменить кодировку консоли. А вот если эта консоль запускается в какой-то ide, то уже не знаю, разве что в настройках где-то

Comment: Вообще, я Ваш код скопировал ничего не меняя у себя в Linux и у меня всё сработало, разве что пришлось писать Tomsk тоже латиницей, как и Михаил Муругов написал

Comment: да, у меня Виндоус, работаю в VS 2017, которая открывает Python-консоль.Про кодировку я не совсем понял, ведь если ввести ее в консоль, она считается вместо названия города @Anton

Comment: Я имел в виду, что какая-то консоль открыта и туда пишется что-то вроде `python3 script_name.py`, если же её visual studio создаёт, то, к сожалению, не знаю, как там настроить что-то, может, в каких-то свойствах есть что-то подходящее, но я с visual studio вовсе не знаком

Comment: @HideME Видимо, этот ответ поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804536/247581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запросе для города Tomsk у меня выдает исключение:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 35: character maps to <undefined>
```

Гуглим код символа `unicode 2212`, находим, что это юникодный знак минус (`'MINUS SIGN' (U+2212)`).

Чтобы в консоли выводилось корректно, можно тупо через `replace` заменять на обычный минус:

```
print(day[0])
print('Температура сейчас: ' + temperature[0].replace('\u2212', '-'))
print('Погода: %s' % weather_type[0], end=', ')
print('%s %s' % (feels[0].lower(), feels[1].replace('\u2212', '-')))
```

Пример вывода:

```
Введите город: Tomsk
Сейчас 23:40
Температура сейчас: -4
Погода: Ясно, ощущается как -9
```

Comment: можно попробовать обойтись без хаков с заменами минусов. Думаю (не тестировал), достаточно консольный шрифт использовать, в котором этот символ есть. [Python 3.7 использует Unicode для отображения в Windows консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/141035/23044).

Comment: @jfs, сначала подумал, что не той версией python запускаю код, но видимо проблема с редактором, из которого запускаю (SciTe-ru), потому что вывод `sys.version` показывает 3.6.5. Если запускать из командной строки, то все нормально, не ругается на юникодные символы.

Comment: в редакторе вывод не в консоль, а перенаправлен может быть (в этом случае используется байтовый интерфейс с кодировкой окружения, которая может не поддерживать желаемые символы, по ссылке это описано). 3.6 версия тоже должна работать.

Comment: Действительно, в перенаправлении была проблема. Убрал перенаправление - юникод заработал (не понятно зачем перенаправление было нужно, если в итоге запускается в стандартной консоли).