# Работа с Русским языком в Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, файлы, кириллица

Нашёл, как мне показалось, очень полезную статью: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Попробовал использовать "Правильное, но сложное решение", ничего к сожалению не вышло. Полностью перешёл с string на wstring, с консольных и файлов потоков на соответствующие расширенные потоки wcout, wcin, wifstream, так же с обычных С-строка на расширенные C-строки. Точнее из консоли получается взять Русские слова, а из файлов нет.
Пример:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    wifstream in{ "input.txt" };
    wstring line;
    getline(in, line);
    wcout << line << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В итоге всё равно кракозябре в консоли и при отладке в "line", аналогичные кракозябры.

Comment: А файл в какой кодировке?

Comment: Все файлы: исходники, "input.txt" - в кодировке UTF - 8

Comment: Перекодируйте файл в UTF-16LE без BOM

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , нет не помогло. Даже английский перестаёт распознавать

Comment: А у вас проблема что `line` не читается, или что в консоль неправильно печатается?

Comment: @VTT проблема в том, что Русские слова после чтения находятся в строке не в том стиле в каком нужно, а именно там кракозябры. Я пробовал менять кодировки c UTF -  8, на UTF - 16. Не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: А в каком виде они находятся в строке?

Comment: @VTT например слово "любовь", хранится в таком стиле: [ссылка](https://b.radikal.ru/b21/1803/e8/b343dd569001.png)

Comment: Можно сделать так `in.imbue(::std::locale{in.getloc(), new ::std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, ::std::consume_header>{}});`.

Answer (score 1):

Пример по ссылке рассказывает о кодировках при работе с консолью, файлы - совершенно отдельная песня. Считать UTF8-файл в Visual C++ проще всего, я думаю, с помощью функции *fopen* (используя [параметр ccs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx#Anchor_3) для указания кодировки).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    

using namespace std;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);     

    wchar_t buf[500]=L"";
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "rt+, ccs=UTF-8");
    fgetws(buf,500,fp);
    fclose(fp);

    wstring line(buf);
    wcout << line << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ого! А можно добавить ссылку на документацию про параметр `ccs`?

Comment: @VladD добавил.

Comment: Круто, не знал. Спасибо!