# Русские символы в С++

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, написал код на С++, чтобы когда вводишь какое-либо слово определенные символы менялись на другие, например:
Ввел "Hello" вывелось "Hezzo", все прекрасно работает, но если ввести русские символы то не работает, а также символы типа: ξ Ē ∑, тоже некорректно отображаются. (setlocale не помогает) Помогите, пожалуйста, хотя бы просто русские буквы присвоить. Заранее спасибо.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

cout << "Hello" << endl;
string s, s1;
cin >> s;
for (const auto& c : s) {
    if (c != 'l') {
        s1 += c;
    }
    else {
        s1 += 'z';
    }
}
cout << s1 << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

прописываешь в начале main

Comment: идентификатор SetConsoleCP и SetConsoleOutputCP не опеределен

Answer (score 0):

Тип данных используй WideString для UNICODE текста

Comment: Сделал wcin, wcout запускается, но все равно с русскими символами не работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно также

```
system("chcp 1251>nul");
```