# Помогите найти ошибку в URL_DECODER написанный С

Tags: c, cgi

Функция почему-то не срабатывает 
URL Выводится, но не декодированный
 вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void url_decode(char* st) {
    char* p = st;
    char hex[3];
    int code;
    do {
        if (*st == "%") {
            hex[0] = *(++st);
            hex[1] = *(++st);
            hex[2] = 0;
            sscanf(hex, "%X", &code);
            *p++ = (char) code;

        } else if (*st == '+') {
            *p++ = " ";
        } else {
            *p++ = *st;
        }
    } while (*st++ != 0);
}

int main(void) {
    char* remote_addr = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    char* query_string = malloc(strlen(getenv("QUERY_STRING")) + 1);
    strcpy(query_string, getenv("QUERY_STRING"));
    url_decode(query_string);
    int num_bytes = atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    char* data = (char*) malloc(num_bytes + 1);


    fread(data, 1, num_bytes, stdin);
    data[num_bytes] = 0;
    url_decode(data);
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    printf("<DOCTYPE html>");
    printf("<html><head>");
    printf("<meta charset = 'UTF-8'>");
    printf("<title>URL - decoder</title>");
    printf("</head>");
    printf("<body>");
    printf("<h1>Мы знаем о вас всё!</h1>");
    printf("<p>Ваш ip-адрес: %s</p>", remote_addr);
    printf("<p>Количество байтов данных: %d</p>", num_bytes);
    printf("<p>Вот параметры которые вы указали: %s</p>", data);
    printf("<p>А вот что мы получили через URL: %s</p>", query_string);
    printf("</body></html>");
}
```

[image: Я поменял ковычки, и это всё декодировалось во что то не понятное]

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Уточните, что именно не работает, что вы ожидаете получить, и что получаете в итоге.

Comment: То есть допустим, я вбиваю в url адрес, после знака вопроса  запрос на русском языке и обычно браузер кодирует эти данные в 16-ричный код. И чтобы понять что в итоге было написано на русском -  для этого он и существует URL_DECODER

b=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB&a=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0 пример кодированных данных

Answer (score 2):

Суть проблемы - проста, если включить побольше вывода ошибок. Компилятор сразу ругается на две строки.

```
if (*st == "%") {
```

и

```
*p++ = " ";
```

символ в кавычках это не символ, а строка с двух символов. И в первой строке происходит сравнение символа (слева) и указателя на строку! справа. Для этого обе части приводятся к int и естественно, условие неверно (первый мегабайт адресов указателей почти всегда не действительный на x86).

В втором случае происходит где то такое же. Указатель на строку с двух символов кастится к char (то есть берется младший байт) и присваивается вместо символа...

Как только поменяете двойные кавычки на одинарные, все вдруг заработает.

Comment: C наступающим,  успехов во всем!

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста картинку которую добавил. Всё изменилось

Comment: Это уже совсем другая проблема. И имя ей - кодировки. Исходная строка у Вас закодированна в UTF-8, а ее немного накладно отображать в виндовой консоли. Начните с этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8