# converting to execution character set : illegal byte sequence

Tags: c

При  использовании в коде  украинской буквы 'i' выдает ошибку из заголовка. Пробовал прописывать setlocale - не помогло. Использую IDE DevC++ . Из-за чего такая проблема и как можно ее исправить?

Comment: `-fexec-charset`, `-finput-charset` какие компилятору передаются? в обеих есть и-десятеричное? `-finput-charset` соответствует действительности?

Comment: Не очень понял вопрос. В настройках прописано -fexec-charset=cp866 -finput-charset=cp1251

Comment: нум, как компилятор и говорит, в `cp866` нет и-десятеричного. из вариантов — смириться и использовать латинскую i; поменять кодировку консоли и флаги компилятора соответственно...

Comment: А на какую кодировку нужно поменять,  что бы работало ?

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, нормальный выбор таже — 1251, `SetConsoleCP(1251);`/`SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);` + поправить/убрать `-fexec-charset`/`-finput-charset`... + смотри общую тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8/