# Как преобразовать UTF-8 в Кириллицу в Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, кодировка, visual-studio-2017

Изначально файл программы набирался в Notepad++(по умолчанию utf-8). Много разрозненного русского текста. При работе через MINGW64 русский выводился без проблем. При использовании файлов в Visual Studio 2017 вылезли непонятные символы.

```
    #include <Windows.h>

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_1251);
```

меняет тип кодировки, но кракозябры не исчезают...

```
#include <clocale>

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
```

ничего не поменял.

Кусочек кода из программы:

```
cout << "Укажите количество датчиков для внесения в базу данных, " <<
"либо 0 для выхода.\n";
```

Как исправить ситуацию, не переписывая русский текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте шрифт в консоли на поддержику кирилицы/UTF8. (ПКМ по окну консоли — шрифты)
Так, как ваш код отлично работает на моем ПК.

Как другой вариант попробуйте использувать **SetConsoleOutputCP**(*CP_UTF8*)

([код взят из ответа на похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575863/how-to-print-utf-8-strings-to-stdcout-on-windows)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    std::cout << u8"Greek: αβγδ\n Привет!\n" << std::flush;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эх, это не мой код был в примере(( Сейчас добавлю кусочек моего русского кода

Comment: В самой консоли 3 шрифта имеется: Consolas, Lucida console и точечный шрифт. Ни один не приводит к положительному результату. К сожалению...

Comment: Но вы же не полностью применили решение по ссылке. Не хватает вызова setvbuf, он в данном случае важен.

Comment: В приведенной ссылке указан код: 
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

class MBuf : public std::stringbuf {
public:
 int sync() {
  fputs(str().c_str(), stdout);
  str("");
  return 0;
 }
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
 SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
 setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);
 MBuf buf;
 std::cout.rdbuf(&buf);
 std::cout << u8"Greek: αβγδ\n" << std::flush;
Этот код сработал!!

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код неправильно использует setlocale. Для UTF8 должно быть так:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8");
```

Кроме того, строковые литералы нужно явно объявить как UTF8:

```
cout << u8"Укажите количество датчиков для внесения в базу данных, ";
```

При соблюдении этих условий, русский (и только русский) текст в консоль выводится будет (но считываться через cin все равно не будет). Если хотите полноценно работать с Unicode в Visual Studio, перейдите на широкие символы, как описано здесь: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)