# Проблема с кодировкой в названиях файлов на кириллице полученных с помощью FtpFindFirstFile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ftp, c++14, wininet

Как правильно вывести в консоль названия файлов на кириллице полученные с FTP сервера с помощью `FtpFindFirstFile` и `InternetFindNextFile`?

Если название на кириллице то выводится вот что `Р?Р?Р?С<Р№ РєР°С'Р°Р>Р?Р?`.

FTP сервер локальный на Windows 10 русская версия.

Мой код состоит из двух файлов:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <io.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib,"wininet")

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "scandir.cpp"

using namespace ::std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Старт" << endl;
    /*if (
        !_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT)
        || !_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U8TEXT)
        || !_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U8TEXT)
        )
    {
        wcout << "Unable to set mode" << endl;
        return 0;
    }*/

    HINTERNET hInternetRoot = InternetOpen("Mozilla", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nullptr, nullptr, NULL);

    if (!hInternetRoot) {
        cout << "InternetOpen error: " << GetLastError() << endl;

        return 0;
    }

    HINTERNET hInternetConnection = InternetConnect(hInternetRoot, "localhost", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "username", "password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, NULL);

    if (!hInternetConnection) {
        cout << "InternetConnect error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternetRoot);

        return 0;
    }

    string command;
    TCHAR currentDir[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD currentDirBuffer = MAX_PATH;

    if (!FtpGetCurrentDirectory(hInternetConnection, currentDir, &currentDirBuffer)) {
        cout << "FtpGetCurrentDirectory error: " << GetLastError() << endl;

        return 0;
    }

    while (true) {
        cout << "FTP>";

        cin >> command;

        if (command == "scandir") {
            vector<string> files;
            int filesLen,
                i;

            files = scanDir(hInternetConnection, currentDir);
            filesLen = files.size();

            for (i = 0; i < filesLen; i++) {
                cout << files[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (command == "setdir") {

        }
        else if (command == "exit") {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid command" << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

И scandir.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"wininet")
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace ::std;

inline vector<string> scanDir(HINTERNET hInternetConnection, string dir)
{
    vector<string> files;

    if (!FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hInternetConnection, dir.c_str())) {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        cout << "FtpSetCurrentDirectory error: " << lastError << endl;

        return files;
    }

    WIN32_FIND_DATA win32FindData;
    HINTERNET hFind = FtpFindFirstFile(hInternetConnection, "*.*", &win32FindData, INTERNET_FLAG_RESYNCHRONIZE, NULL);

    if (!hFind) {
        cout << "FtpFindFirstFile error: " << GetLastError() << endl;

        return files;
    }

    files.push_back(win32FindData.cFileName);

    while (InternetFindNextFile(hFind, &win32FindData)) {
        files.push_back(win32FindData.cFileName);
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(hFind);

    return files;
}
```

Пробовал перевести всю программу на UTF и использовать функции и типы которые начинаются и заканчиваются на `W`, как описано вот здесь [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8), то пользы не дало, тоже абракадабра только другая.

Причем вот эта программа отлично выводит названия из той же директории:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    int counter = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    char path[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };


    std::cout << "Enter path: ";
    cin >> path;

    strcat_s(path, "\\*.*");
    hFind = FindFirstFile(path, (LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA)& FindFileData);

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {

            cout << FindFileData.cFileName << '\n';
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return 0;
}
```

Я не вижу какие либо принципиальные отличия в поиске и выводе названий файлов в моем коде `scandir.cpp` и в последней программе.
Думаю у функции `FtpFindFirstFile` есть какие то особенности.

Answer (score 0):

> Думаю у функции FtpFindFirstFile есть какие то особенности

Похоже, FtpFindFirstFile, даже Юникод-версия, не поддерживают имена файлов в кодировке UTF-8. Первый стандарт FTP разрешал имена файлов только из ASCII-символов, но впоследствии была добавлена необязательная поддержка имен на UTF-8 (кодировки ANSI FTP не использует). Но реализация FTP в WinInet как будто, даже если сервер поддерживает UTF-8, обрабатывает имена файлов, используя текущую системную кодовую страницу ANSI. Поэтому единственный выход - вручную перекодировать через MultiByteToWideChar:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"wininet")

inline std::vector<std::wstring> scanDir(HINTERNET hInternetConnection, std::wstring dir)
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> files;

    if (!FtpSetCurrentDirectoryW(hInternetConnection, dir.c_str())) {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        std::wcout << L"FtpSetCurrentDirectory error: " << lastError << std::endl;

        return files;
    }

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA win32FindData;
    HINTERNET hFind = FtpFindFirstFileA(hInternetConnection, "*.*", &win32FindData, INTERNET_FLAG_RESYNCHRONIZE, NULL);

    if (!hFind) {
        std::wcout << L"FtpFindFirstFile error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

        return files;
    }

    WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH] = L"";

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, win32FindData.cFileName, sizeof(win32FindData.cFileName), buf, MAX_PATH);
    files.push_back(buf);

    while (InternetFindNextFileA(hFind, &win32FindData)) {
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, win32FindData.cFileName, sizeof(win32FindData.cFileName), buf, MAX_PATH);
        files.push_back(buf);
    }

    InternetCloseHandle(hFind);

    return files;
}

int main()
{   
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);

    std::wcout << L"Старт" << std::endl;    

    HINTERNET hInternetRoot = InternetOpenW(L"Mozilla", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nullptr, nullptr, NULL);

    if (!hInternetRoot) {
        std::wcout << L"InternetOpen error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }

    HINTERNET hInternetConnection = InternetConnectW(
        hInternetRoot, L"server", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, L"user", L"password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, NULL
    );

    if (!hInternetConnection) {
        std::wcout << L"InternetConnect error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternetRoot);

        return 0;
    }

    std::wstring command;
    WCHAR currentDir[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD currentDirBuffer = MAX_PATH;

    if (!FtpGetCurrentDirectoryW(hInternetConnection, currentDir, &currentDirBuffer)) {
        std::wcout << L"FtpGetCurrentDirectory error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
    
    while (true) {
        std::wcout << L"FTP>";

        WCHAR cmd[200] = L"";
        std::wcin.getline(cmd, 200);
        command.assign(cmd);        

        if (command == L"scandir") {
            std::vector<std::wstring> files;
            int filesLen,
                i;

            files = scanDir(hInternetConnection, currentDir);
            filesLen = files.size();

            for (i = 0; i < filesLen; i++) {
                std::wcout << files[i].c_str() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else if (command == L"setdir") {

        }
        else if (command == L"exit") {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            std::wcout << L"Invalid command" << std::endl;
        }

        std::wcout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```