# Вылетает после ввода символа

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char someChar;
char someText[] = "Passport";
puts(someText);
printf("\n Введите символ: ");
scanf("%c", &someChar);
int lenght = sizeof(someText)/sizeof(someText[0]);
int count = 0;
for(int i = 1; i<lenght; i++)
{
if (someText[i] > someChar) count++;
}
printf("\n Символы, которые больше %c: %i", someChar, count);
return 0;
}
```

Программа для подсчета символов больше заданного в строке, собственно программа закрывается без каких-либо ошибок сразу после ввода символа и нажатия Enter. Собственно, вопрос: что не так?

Comment: Что значит "закрывается"? Ваша программа - консольное приложение, которое не может "открываться" или "закрываться". Запускайте ее из консоли и смотрите вывод. Не забывайте только перевод строки в конце вывода ставить. Что это вообще за странная манера ставить `\n` в начале?

Comment: И почему у вас цикл начинается с 1?

Comment: Как минимум длину строки нужно искать через strlen. sizeof(someText) всегда вернёт 4 на х32 и 8 х64. В цикле нумерация с 0. У вас консоль не закрывается? Может такое быть, что вы просто не успеваете прочесть вывод?

Comment: да, через командную строку все работает как надо. а вот если запускать с файла, то видимо да, не успеваю прочесть вывод

Comment: а еще вопрос. в программе не поддерживается кириллица, как я понял, все в символах, вместо нормальных слов. Как сделать читабельный вариант?

Comment: Проблему решил, скомпилировав программу в другом компиляторе, теперь все корректно

Comment: @Дмитрий Зиненко: Неверно. `sizeof(someText)` в данном случае вернет именно длину строки плюс 1. `someText` - это массив.

Answer (score 1):

> в программе не поддерживается кириллица

Это сложный вопрос. Он распадается на три:

1. Используемая кодировка
2. Поддержка кириллицы в рамках ОС
3. Поддержка кириллицы в Вашей программе.

Если Вы работаете под Windows, то (скорее всего) кодировка по умолчанию cp1251.  Тогда надо в начале программы прописать

```
Setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru-RU");
```

([Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8))
И всё будет работать, за исключением того, что само понятие "символ, который больше" станет довольно туманным.

Если вы работает в Linux (где кодировка по умолчанию UTF-8), то с отображение символов кириллицы никаких проблем не будет, вот только вся логика Вашей программы накрывается медным тазом. Это происходи потому, что в UTF-8 один (!!!) символ может занимать один байт, два байта... Поэтому Ваша метода расчёт длины строки и сравнения символов на больше/меньше становится неприменимой.