# Glfw С++ Ввод русского текста с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, visual-studio-2010, glfw

Питаюсь вводить текст с клавиатуры и сразу отправляю в консоль, с английским без проблем но вместо русского вводить какие то цифры и английские буквы.

вот функция обработки и регистрации

Русский в консоли включён!

```
void character_callback( GLFWwindow *window, unsigned int codepoint )
{
    std::cout << (char)codepoint;
    Text+=(char)codepoint;
}

glfwSetCharCallback( window, character_callback );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью glfw вводить кириллицу?

==========================================
 Помог Коментарии, сделал таблицу соответствия кодировок и всё. Ответ помог выводить в консоль спасибо. Но мне нужно было имен о преобразовать в обычный char. Я это решил. всем спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно работать с `codepoint` как с Unicode-символом, вы же вообще «обрезаете» его до `char`.

Comment: спасибо, может вы знаете, В какой кодировке переедаться текст если я отправляю его в функцию. пример print("мой текст")? или как ansi символ преобразовать а не обрезать в char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нам нужно переключить режим стандартных потоков ввода/вывода с помощью функции [`_setmod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019)<sup>1</sup> (делаем это где-нибудь в `main`, например):

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin),  _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
```

Согласно [документации GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/input_guide.html), мы можем рассматривать `codepoint` как UTF-32 символ с нативным порядком байтов. Тогда ваша функция `character_callback` может выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
void character_callback(GLFWwindow *window, unsigned int codepoint)
{
    const wchar_t wideChar = codepoint;       
    std::wcout << wideChar;

    <...>
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Подробнее про русский язык в консоли смотрите в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/185348) ответе.