# Visual studio 2019 не выводит русский текст. Что делать?

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 200   
void main() {
    char str[MAX_SIZE];
    int i = 0, j;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    printf("Введите строку (Не больше 200 символов): ");
    fgets(str, MAX_SIZE, stdin);
    OemToChar(str, str);
    if (str[0] == ' ') {
        str[0] = str[1];
    }
    while (str[i] != ' ') i++;
    for (j = strlen(str) + 10; j > i; j--)
    str[j] = str[j - 6];
    str[i + 1] = 'h';
    str[i + 2] = 'e';
    str[i + 3] = 'l';
    str[i + 4] = 'l';
    str[i + 5] = 'o';
    str[i + 6] = ' ';
    printf("Результат: \n");
    puts(str);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru");

Comment: Не помагает((( Тот же результат

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Русский язык в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)