# Ввожу русские буквы, выводит непонятные символы C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Написал программку для расставления букв в алфавитном порядке в любом слове. Поставил `setlocale(0, "rus")`. После обработки выдаёт непонятные символы. Если на латинице то всё нормально. Что делать, подскажите пожалуйста?

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    string a, b;
    getline(cin, a);
    getline(cin, b);
    // если в строке `a` не нашли символ, который нет в строке `b`
    if (a.find_first_not_of(b) == string::npos) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i)
            //проверяеешь является ли символ буквой
            if (isalpha(b[i]))
                b.erase(i--, 1);
        cout << a << endl << b;
    }
    else {     //сортируешь в алфавитном порядке
        sort(a.begin(), a.end());
        cout << a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте  `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключите `windows.h` и напишите две строки:

```
setConsoleCP(1251);
setConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Это самый простой способ.

Больше информации про `setlocale` и ее использование [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459154/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)